# Where is Round() in C++?

Tags: c++, rounding

#### Duplicate of: [round() for float in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c)

---

I'm using VS2008 and I've included math.h but I still can't find a round function.  Does it exist?

I'm seeing a bunch of "add 0.5 and cast to int" solutions on google.  Is that the best practice?

Comment: add 0.5 and cast to int won't work for negative numbers. The cast truncates (so it rounds -4.5 to -4). So attempting to round -5.0 will give you an output of-4 with this method. Replace the cast with ceil() and it should work.

But yes, you have to implement your own, or find it in a 3rd party lib.

Comment: Er, assume I wrote floor() above, of course. To use ceil, you'd have to subtract 0.5

Comment: @jalf as I noted in [my answer to the dup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24348037/1708801) there are a lot of issues with rolling your own and today even if you are stuck with *C++03* boost would be a better recommendation than attempting to roll your own.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You may use C++11's [`std::round()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round).

If you are still stuck with older standards, you may use [`std::floor()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor), which always rounds to the lower number, and [`std::ceil()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil), which always rounds to the higher number.

To get the normal rounding behaviour, you would indeed use `floor(i + 0.5)`.

This way will give you problems with negative numbers, a workaround for that problem is by using ceil() for negative numbers:

```
double round(double number)
{
    return number < 0.0 ? ceil(number - 0.5) : floor(number + 0.5);
}
```

Another, cleaner, but more resource-intensive, way is to make use of a stringstream and the input-/output-manipulators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

double round(double val, int precision)
{
    std::stringstream s;
    s << std::setprecision(precision) << std::setiosflags(std::ios_base::fixed) << val;
    s >> val;
    return val;
}
```

Only use the second approach if you are not low on resources and/or need to have control over the precision.

Comment: You think it's *cleaner* to convert to a string and back?

Comment: Yes, using the +0.5-technique you will encounter problems with negative numbers and you also don't have control over the precision.

Comment: +0.5 should work fine as long as you use floor(). Anyway, then it becomes a question of correctness, and not which is cleaner.

Comment: what problems are there with negative numbers?  if you don't need control precision then the stringstream solution is way slower for no reason.  maybe a template-specialization would make sense here, if you really want to give precision control.

Comment: also, i should remind you that 0.5 is represented as an exact number.

Comment: Needed also to include <iomanip> (using MSVC 2012) to use the round function.

Comment: I prefer `copysignf(floorf(fabs(x) + 0.5f), x)` as it's branchless and the code that simulates the branch is literally bin-ops (`abs` -> `&~0x80000000`, copysign is a bit transfer, etc)

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24348037/1708801), there is also `trunc` and `boost` available. Also see my link's to  Pascal Cuoq's articles on why rolling your own can be very tricky.

Comment: @wilhelmtell "what problems are there with negative numbers?" --> in the corner case of `round(-0.0)`, this answer returns `0.0`.  `-0.0` may be expected.

Comment: Question starts with "I'm using VS2008..." and the answer starts with "You may use C++11's..." Don't you think there is some contradiction here?
There is no std::round() function in VC2008.

Comment: Note that the +0.5 trick is not completely right: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/02/nearbyintf1

Answer (score 14):

Using `floor(num + 0.5)` won't work for negative numbers.  In that case you need to use `ceil(num - 0.5)`.

```
double roundToNearest(double num) {
    return (num > 0.0) ? floor(num + 0.5) : ceil(num - 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There actually isn't a round function in Microsoft math.h.
However you could use the static method Math::Round() instead.
(Depending on your project type.)

Comment: Visual studio now supports round [see my comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c#comment37681329_485525) also see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24348037/1708801) for what I think is a full set of alternatives in a case where you can not use a more modern compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's best practice or not but using the 0.5 technique with a floor() seems to be the way to go.