# Pixel Values and Image dimension

Tags: matlab, opencv

For a given image with height = 17, and width = 11.(image A),

Are the following statements equivalent?

In Matlab:
halfHeight = round(17/2); (answer = 9)

In C++:
int halfHeight = ceil(17/2); (answer = 9)

For pixel access, how can I be sure that I'm accessing the correct pixel values?

Comment: To add the above, I've seen some post stated we need to plus 1 for pixel access in C++. Why do we need to plus 1?

Comment: Can you tell us a sample code where you want to use it ?

Comment: In Matlab:
[H,W] = size(image);
H = round(H/2); 
half_character = imcrop(image,[0 0 W H]);

I want to write it in C++, opencv

Comment: matlab is uses base 1 index, C++ uses base 0 index. You may want to subtract 1 when using C++.

Comment: Is this right?
IplImage* half_character = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
half_character = cvCloneImage(image);
cvSetImageROI(half_character, cvRect(0, 0, width, halfHeight));

Comment: Is image A supposed to be linked here?

Comment: I'm suppose image A is just an example. I wonder if what i do is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you do the calculation:

```
17/2=8.5
```

`ceil(x)` will compute the closest integer which is greater than `x`

`round(x)` will compute the closest integer. However both `8` and `9` are as close to `8.5`. So the convention is that it is equal to `9`, in that case.

Similarly `round(1.5)=2`, `round(2.5)=3`

Comment: I can't find any equivalent round(matlab) in C++. Therefore, I'm using ceil. It seems that cvRound(opencv) is not the same as round(matlab).

Comment: This answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554204/where-is-round-in-c

Answer (score 0):

From the answer  [Where is Round() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554204/where-is-round-in-c) , we can answer the question.

However, in Matlab it also has explicit definition.
From the Mathworks http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/round.html , we can see

> Y = round(X) rounds the elements of X to the nearest integers. Positive elements with a fractional part of 0.5 round up to the nearest positive integer. Negative elements with a fractional part of -0.5 round down to the nearest negative integer. For complex X, the imaginary and real parts are rounded independently.

Of course, we can see

> B = ceil(A) rounds the elements of A to the nearest integers greater than or equal to A. For complex A, the imaginary and real parts are rounded independently.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ceil.html

Then we can easily know why round(8.5)=9 and ceil(8.5)=9.

Comment: Great explanation. 
Btw, in Matlab, there is ceil and floor as well.