# How to round to the nearest fourth

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a way to round a number to nearest number that can be divided by 4 without remainder

Comment: Give it a try, post your code, and we'll help you make it work.

Comment: Looks like your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554204/where-is-round-in-c

Comment: Does this *way* need to do something specific with `2`?

Answer (score 2):

```
num = std::round(num / 4.0) * 4.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some pseudo code.  Probably not the most efficient way, but...

```
if num mod 4 == 0 then you are good
if num mod 4 == 1 then subtract 1
if num mod 4 == 2 then you decide (subtract/add 2)
if num mod 4 == 3 then add 1
```

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley's answer seems to be what you are looking for as well.

Comment: he might be using floating point numbers

Comment: he very well could be.  That's why I wrote pseudo code.  There are different ways to check for equality with different assumed data types.  Good to point that out though.

Answer (score -3):

Use the following MACRO:

```
#define ALIGN4(len) (((len) + 3) & ~3) // round up to 4 items
```

Comment: Downvote for macro, especially in C++ code.  Also for using low-level operators instead of clearly arithmetic options.

Comment: he is looking for the nearest number, not necessary bigger one