# Why is floor() so slow?

Tags: c, performance, visual-c++, x86, intel

I wrote some code recently (ISO/ANSI C), and was surprised at the poor performance it achieved. Long story short, it turned out that the culprit was the `floor()` function. Not only it was slow, but it did not vectorize (with Intel compiler, aka ICL).

Here are some benchmarks for performing floor for all cells in a 2D matrix:

```
VC:  0.10
ICL: 0.20
```

Compare that to a simple cast:

```
VC:  0.04
ICL: 0.04
```

How can `floor()` be that much slower than a simple cast?! It does essentially the same thing (apart for negative numbers).
2nd question: Does someone know of a super-fast `floor()` implementation?

PS: Here is the loop that I was benchmarking:

```
void Floor(float *matA, int *intA, const int height, const int width, const int width_aligned)
{
    float *rowA=NULL;
    int   *intRowA=NULL;
    int   row, col;

    for(row=0 ; row<height ; ++row){
        rowA = matA + row*width_aligned;
        intRowA = intA + row*width_aligned;
#pragma ivdep
        for(col=0 ; col<width; ++col){
            /*intRowA[col] = floor(rowA[col]);*/
            intRowA[col] = (int)(rowA[col]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A couple of things make floor slower than a cast and prevent vectorization.

The most important one:

floor can modify the global state. If you pass a value that is too huge to be represented as an integer in float format, the **errno** variable gets set to **EDOM**. Special handling for NaNs is done as well. All this behavior is for applications that want to detect the overflow case and handle the situation somehow (don't ask me how).

Detecting these problematic conditions is not simple and makes up more than 90% of the execution time of floor. The actual rounding is cheap and could be inlined/vectorized. Also It's a lot of code, so inlining the whole floor-function would make your program run slower.

Some compilers have special compiler flags that allow the compiler to optimize away some of the rarely used c-standard rules. For example **GCC** can be told that you're not interested in errno at all. To do so pass **-fno-math-errno** or **-ffast-math**. ICC and VC may have similar compiler flags.

Btw - You can roll your own floor-function using simple casts. You just have to handle the negative and positive cases differently. That may be a lot faster if you don't need the special handling of overflows and NaNs.

Answer (score 21):

If you are going to convert the result of the `floor()` operation to an int, and if you aren't worried about overflow, then the following code is much faster than `(int)floor(x)`:

```
inline int int_floor(double x)
{
  int i = (int)x; /* truncate */
  return i - ( i > x ); /* convert trunc to floor */
}
```

Comment: you should probably use `static inline` instead of `inline` if you want to put this into a header file - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10245969/48015

Answer (score 13):

Branch-less Floor and Ceiling (better utilize the pipiline) no error check

```
int f(double x)
{
    return (int) x - (x < (int) x); // as dgobbi above, needs less than for floor
}

int c(double x)
{
    return (int) x + (x > (int) x);
}
```

or using floor

```
int c(double x)
{
    return -(f(-x));
}
```

Comment: Umm. `floor` gives incorrect answers for negative integers and `ceil` incorrect answers for positive ones.

Comment: Thanks imallett.  Code should be fine now.

Answer (score 4):

The actual fastest implementation **for a *large* array** on modern x86 CPUs would be

- **change the MXCSR FP rounding mode to round towards -Infinity (aka `floor`)**.  In C, this should be possible with `fenv` stuff, or `_mm_getcsr` / `_mm_setcsr`.
- loop over the array doing `_mm_cvtps_epi32` on SIMD vectors, converting 4 `float`s to 32-bit integer using the current rounding mode.  (And storing the result vectors to the destination.)

  [`cvtps2dq xmm0, [rdi]`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTPS2DQ.html) is a single micro-fused uop on any Intel or AMD CPU since K10 or Core 2.   (https://agner.org/optimize/)  Same for the 256-bit AVX version, with YMM vectors.
- restore the current rounding mode to the normal IEEE default mode, using the original value of the MXCSR.  (round-to-nearest, with even as a tiebreak)

**This allows loading + converting + storing 1 SIMD vector of results per clock cycle, just as fast as with truncation**.  (SSE2 has a special FP->int conversion instruction for truncation, exactly because it's very commonly needed by C compilers.  In the bad old days with x87, even `(int)x` required changing the x87 rounding mode to truncation and then back.  [`cvttps2dq` for packed float->int with truncation](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTTPS2DQ.html) (note the extra `t` in the mnemonic).  Or for scalar, going from XMM to integer registers, [`cvttss2si`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTTSS2SI.html) or `cvttsd2si` for scalar `double` to scalar integer.

With some loop unrolling and/or good optimization, this should be possible without bottlenecking on the front-end, just 1-per-clock store throughput assuming no cache-miss bottlenecks.  (And on Intel before Skylake, also bottlenecked on 1-per-clock packed-conversion throughput.)  i.e. **16, 32, or 64 bytes per cycle, using SSE2, AVX, or AVX512.**

---

Without changing the current rounding mode, you need SSE4.1 `roundps` to round a `float` to the nearest integer `float` using your choice of rounding modes.  Or you could use one of the tricks shows in other answers that work for floats with small enough magnitude to fit in a signed 32-bit integer, since that's your ultimate destination format anyway.)

---

(With the right compiler options, like `-fno-math-errno`, and the right `-march` or `-msse4` options, compilers can inline `floor` using `roundps`, or the scalar and/or double-precision equivalent, e.g. `roundsd xmm1, xmm0, 1`, but this costs 2 uops and has 1 per 2 clock throughput on Haswell for scalar or vectors.  Actually, gcc8.2 will inline `roundsd` for `floor` even without any fast-math options, [as you can see on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%0A__m128d+vfloor(__m128d+x)+%7B+return+_mm_floor_pd(x)%3B+%7D%0A%0A%23include+%3Cmath.h%3E%0A%0Adouble+f(double+x)+%7B+return+floor(x)%3B+%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50.83418951162773,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B17+-O3+-Wall+-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:49.16581048837228,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).  But that's with `-march=haswell`.  It's unfortunately not baseline for x86-64, so you need to enable it if your machine supports it.)

Comment: +1. Sidenote: Somehow icc doesn't seem to know that `vcvtps2dq` depends on the value of the MXCSR control and status register. In [this example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qyC6VB) the order of `x=_mm_cvtps_epi32(y);` and `_MM_SET_ROUNDING_MODE(_MM_ROUND_NEAREST);` has been exchanged by icc.

Comment: @wim: Yeah I wondered if that would be a problem.  I should add something about `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON`, if that works for any actual compilers.  ([Does FENV\_ACCESS pragma exist in C++11 and higher?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36218367)).  And/or try ICC compile options like [`-fp-model strict`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522979) to tell it that you modify the FP rounding mode.  (The ICC default is `-fp-model fast=1`.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `floor()` is extremely slow on all platforms since it has to implement a lot of behaviour from the IEEE fp spec. You can't really use it in inner loops.

I sometimes use a macro to approximate floor():

```
#define PSEUDO_FLOOR( V ) ((V) >= 0 ? (int)(V) : (int)((V) - 1))
```

It does not behave exactly as `floor()`: for example, `floor(-1) == -1` but `PSEUDO_FLOOR(-1) == -2`, but it's close enough for most uses.

Comment: Naive implementation. PSEUDO_FLOOR( x++ ) would break this.

Comment: Yes, Charlie. It would be better to make it an inline function.

Answer (score 2):

An actually branchless version that requires a single conversion between floating point and integer domains would shift the value `x` to all positive or all negative range, then cast/truncate and shift it back.

```
long fast_floor(double x)
{
    const unsigned long offset = ~(ULONG_MAX >> 1);
    return (long)((unsigned long)(x + offset) - offset);
}

long fast_ceil(double x) {
    const unsigned long offset = ~(ULONG_MAX >> 1);
    return (long)((unsigned long)(x - offset) + offset );
}
```

As pointed in the comments, this implementation relies on the temporary value `x +- offset` not overflowing.

On 64-bit platforms, the original code using int64_t intermediate value will result in three instruction kernel, the same available for int32_t reduced range floor/ceil, where `|x| < 0x40000000` --

```
inline int floor_x64(double x) {
   return (int)((int64_t)(x + 0x80000000UL) - 0x80000000LL);
}
inline int floor_x86_reduced_range(double x) {
   return (int)(x + 0x40000000) - 0x40000000;
}
```

Comment: does this depend on `long` being wider than `int` for correctness with the full range of `int` results?  That's not the case on many 32-bit platforms, and on x86-64 Windows (a LLP64 ABI where int and long are both 32-bit).  So maybe you should use `long long`.  But still a nice idea.

Comment: Yes (that is long int being wider than int), but I think this can be mitigated by casting to unsigned int.

Comment: `double` -> `unsigned long` is somewhat slow on x86.  https://godbolt.org/z/1UqaQw.  x86-64 doesn't have an instruction for that until AVX512, only for `double` -> signed integer.  On 32-bit x86 where `unsigned long` is a 32-bit type, x87 `fistp` can do FP -> 64-bit signed integer, and you can use the low half of that as `unsigned int`.  But truncation requires either SSE3 `fisttp` or changing the rounding mode.  SSE2 can't do truncation to a 32-bit unsigned integer or 64-bit signed integer either.  The other answers are probably more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

1. They do not do the same thing. floor() is a function. Therefore, using it incurs a function call, allocating a stack frame, copying of parameters and retrieving the result.
   Casting is not a function call, so it uses faster mechanisms (I believe that it may use registers to process the values).
2. Probably floor() is already optimized.
3. Can you squeeze more performance out of your algorithm? Maybe switching rows and columns may help? Can you cache common values? Are all your compiler's optimizations on? Can you switch an operating system? a compiler?
   [Jon Bentley's Programming Pearls](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/) has a great review of possible optimizations.

Comment: Never assume that the standard libraries are optimized. They are almost always extremely slow. You can sometimes get major speed gains by using your own custom code.

Comment: floor() is a function, but it's commonly used enough for compilers to treat it as a builtin, like memcpy or sqrt and inline it if they want to.  e.g. GCC `-O2` for x86-64 inlines it even when it takes multiple instructions, without SSE4.1 for `roundss` / `roundps` (https://godbolt.org/z/5jdTvcx7x).  But yeah, without SSE4.1 it's a lot slower than fp->int with truncation, which has faster HW support.

Answer (score -3):

**Fast double round**

```
double round(double x)
{
    return double((x>=0.5)?(int(x)+1):int(x));
}
```

---

**Terminal log**

test custom_1 8.3837

test native_1 18.4989

test custom_2 8.36333

test native_2 18.5001

test custom_3 8.37316

test native_3 18.5012

---

**Test**

```
void test(char* name, double (*f)(double))
{
    int it = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    clock_t begin = clock();

    for(int i=0; i<it; i++)
    {
        f(double(i)/1000.0);
    }
    clock_t end = clock();

    cout << "test " << name << " " << double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    test("custom_1",round);
    test("native_1",std::round);
    test("custom_2",round);
    test("native_2",std::round);
    test("custom_3",round);
    test("native_3",std::round);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Result**

Type casting and using your brain is ~3 times faster than using native functions.

Comment: Your `round()` function doesn't work. You need to either use a floating-point modulo to check whether the fractional part is greater than 0.5, or you could use the old `(int) (double_value + 0.5)` trick to perform rounding.

Comment: For FP->int with round-to-nearest, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47347224/224132.