# Inline function "undefined symbols" error

Tags: objective-c, c, compiler-errors, inline, linker-errors

I want to write an inline function, but I get an error. How can I fix it?

Error information:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_XYInRect", referenced from:
      -[BeginAnimation ccTouchesEnded:withEvent:] in BeginAnimation.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Code:

```
CGPoint location = CGPointMake(60, 350);

if (XYInRect(location, 53, 338, 263, 369)) {

}

inline BOOL XYInRect(CGPoint location, float MixX, float MixY, float MaxX ,float MaxY){
    if (location.x >MixX && location.y >MixY && location.x <MaxX && location.y <MaxY) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;

    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but can't you just use CGRectContainsPoint instead of rolling your own?

Comment: Compiling with the -O2 optimization switch worked for me, as suggested in http://StackOverflow.com/questions/18939482/clang-linker-fails-if-at-least-o2-wasnt-used and another question I can no longer find.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Clang [defaults to C99](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#inline) and not [GNU sematics](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html#Inline), which means a raw `inline` is different from both `static inline` and `extern inline`.

In particular, a raw `inline` means that the function still has external linkage, but the inline definition does not provide the external one (you'd need `extern inline` for that).

What this means is that you need an additional `extern` definition in a different translation unit or linking will fail. However, you're probably looking for `static inline`.

Comment: Note that by the time XCode 8.1 was released (2016-10-27), the default language for (Apple's release of) `clang` was no longer C99 but C11. GCC 5.0 and later also default to C11 (but previously defaulted to C90).  This is only a minor detail; it doesn't affect the rest of the answer.

Comment: This issue occurs even in a single translation unit though, where it is not referenced from anywhere else.

Comment: For example, `inline int foo () {} int main() { foo();  }`

Answer (score 0):

I think `XYInRect()` needs to be known prior to being used. Move the function definition to some place in the file before you call it.