# symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s (linker command failed with exit code 1)

Tags: objective-c, linker-errors

When I build in Xcode 5 for IOS7 I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CIFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UIImage+Filter.o
  "_kCIInputImageKey", referenced from:
      -[UIImage(Filter) filterWithPreset:] in UIImage+Filter.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CIImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UIImage+Filter.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CIContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UIImage+Filter.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I notice that the error goes away if I remove the UIImage+Filter.h/m file and UIImageView+Filter.h/m

Comment: Did you link to the CoreImage framework?

Comment: Wow No I didn't, and this was the error...How did you understand???

Comment: @Alessandro `CI` prefix on classes... or just google... it's pretty trivial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inline function "undefined symbols" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243018/inline-function-undefined-symbols-error)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy... Make sure you import CoreImage framework