# Undefined symbols for CIFilter even though I have included CoreImage.h

Tags: objective-c, core-image

I have these code to print QRCode on `Tools.m`:

```
#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>
...
+ (UIImage *)renderQRCodeFrom:(NSString *)source withImageViewFrameSize:(CGSize)imageViewFrameSize {

    NSString *qrString = source;
    NSData *stringData = [qrString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    CIFilter *qrFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIQRCodeGenerator"];
    [qrFilter setValue:stringData forKey:@"inputMessage"];
    [qrFilter setValue:@"H" forKey:@"inputCorrectionLevel"];

    CIImage *qrImage = qrFilter.outputImage;
    float scaleX = imageViewFrameSize.width / qrImage.extent.size.width;
    float scaleY = imageViewFrameSize.height / qrImage.extent.size.height;

    qrImage = [qrImage imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleX, scaleY)];

    return [UIImage imageWithCIImage:qrImage scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
}
```

But when I compile it, it shows error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CIFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Tools.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why this error happens? I have included `CoreImage.h` properly, and as far as I know, I can't find such similar error on the web, meaning that this error is unusual. I can CMD+click the CIFilter though, and it leads to `CoreImage/CIFilter.h`.

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE(10_4, 5_0)
@interface CIFilter : NSObject <NSSecureCoding, NSCopying>
{
    void *_priv[8];
}
...
```

My project deployment target is set to iOS 8.0. I'm using Obj C without ARC in this project.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about this question. The answer is don't forget to CoreImage *framework* in the project target > General > scroll to the bottom.

Sigh.

[symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s (linker command failed with exit code 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887624/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-armv7s-linker-command-failed-with-exit-cod)