# clang linker error when compiling simple C program on OS X

Tags: c, clang, linker-errors

I was building [this code](https://web.archive.org/web/20180924040224/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter10/kbdleds/download/keyboard_leds.c) from [this article](https://googlemac.blogspot.com/2008/04/manipulating-keyboard-leds-through.html)

I was using the recommended command to build it: `gcc -Wall -o keyboard_leds keyboard_leds.c -framework IOKit -framework CoreFoundation`

```
$ curl -O http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter10/kbdleds/download/keyboard_leds.c
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 11542  100 11542    0     0   139k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  140k

$ clang -Wall -o keyboard_leds keyboard_leds.c -framework IOKit -framework CoreFoundation
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_print_errmsg_if_err", referenced from:
      _create_hid_interface in keyboard_leds-d14ed5.o
  "_print_errmsg_if_io_err", referenced from:
      _create_hid_interface in keyboard_leds-d14ed5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

$
```

The code is very straightforward, if a little dated (6 years). I cannot see any mention anywhere of the symbols that begin with the underscore. I'm probably missing something simple, but I'm completely stumped about where these symbols come from.

What gives? I can comment out the calls to get it to compile.

Comment: It is a clang C99-compliance thing. You can [**read more about it here**](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#inline), but in your case the simplest work-around is to remove the `inline` preamble from the *definitions* (where the *code* is, not the prototypes). You could add `-std=gnu89`, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: Oh that is bizarre. I almost tried that... I tried removing the *declarations* (as I saw them to serve no purpose) but to no avail. Thanks! Make that your answer and i will accept

Comment: Based on the explanation that was linked, it would appear that compiling with optimizations will result in a successful compilation. I verified this with `-O2`.

Comment: It will, but obviously its a bear to debug (I can confirm, btw that compiling with `-O2` does indeed build successfully, and it is likely I'm running a clang similar to yours). I'm resisting posting an answer until I can confirm with reasonable assurance this isn't a duplicate of something else. It would seem this should have bit someone in the past. If I can't find anything by this evening I'll post something akin to my first comment. Hope thats ok.

Comment: Ha! Found one: [This looks to be the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243018/inline-function-undefined-symbols-error).

Comment: Dang. Such SO-fu. Nice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inline function "undefined symbols" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243018/inline-function-undefined-symbols-error)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre nice. You linked the same one WhozCraig did in 2014 :)

Comment: Because I stumbled on his link and it really seems to be a duplicate to me.