# Rounding to the second decimal spot

Tags: c++, rounding

how do i round to the second decimal point in C++.
thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you need to round for further math or just to print?

Answer (score 3):

You can multiply by 100 and then round to an integer. Then put the decimal point after the first 2 digits.

For example:

```
void round(double x)
{
   double y = 100 * x;
   int rounded = (int)(y + 0.5);
   printf("%lf rounded = %d.%02d\n", x, rounded / 100, rounded % 100);
}
```

Comment: Note that this will still suffer from IEEE 754's accuracy problems, which is why such things are usually left until output.

Comment: No, this bit won't. The edge case for rounding is 0.5, which is perfectly representable as a binary fraction. I.e. numbers up to `xxxx.01111111111111111` are rounded down to `xxxx`, and numbers from `xxxx.10000000000000000` up are rounded up to `xxxx+1`. (if you _already_ suffer from IEEE754 accuracy problems, it can be surprising though. For instance, if you think that `y` contains `0.145` - it can't.)

Answer (score 3):

When printing doubles you can specify the precision:

> f,F
>
> The double argument is rounded and converted to decimal notation in the style [-]ddd.ddd, where the number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification. If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6; if the precision is explicitly zero, no decimal-point character appears. If a decimal point appears, at least one digit appears before it.

Try:

```
printf("%f rounded = %.2f\n", x, x);
```

The same thing in C++

```
std::cout << x << " rounded = " << std::setprecision(2) << x << "\n";
```

Comment: Curios why somebody thinks this is wrong?

Comment: Thecnically, this doesn't round `x`, even though it outputs a rounded representation of `x` (not my downvote btw)

Comment: My argument there is that the question did not specify what he wants rounded (the variable representation or the output of the value). Trying to round a floating point value is doomed to failure (because of rounding issues). Another interpretation is that the OP wants to have a decimal value.

Answer (score 2):

If you're expecting an exact result in a `double` or `float`, it may be impossible. Many numbers that can be exactly represented in two decimal digits can't be represented in the base 2 floating point numbers at all, and all you'll get is the nearest equivalent. For example you might find that `1.10` is stuck at `1.1000000000000001` no matter how many times you try to round it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which kind of rounding you need.
Assuming rounding to the nearest integer:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double round(double x) { return floor(x * 100 + 0.5) / 100; }

int main()
{
    printf("%g\n", round(12.345));
}
```

It prints 12.35.

Or if you just want to print a number rounded to two digits after decimal point:

```
printf("%.2f\n", x);
```

Comment: You didn't try your code with 0.145, did you?

Comment: Actually the OP haven't specify the tie breaking rules if you mean that.

Comment: @Roland Illig: probably not, since IEEE754 cannot represent it. `0.14999999999` should of course be rounded to "0.14"

Comment: @Roland Illig: As MSalters correctly pointed out 0.145 should be rounded to 0.14 which the code does. So what is your point?

Comment: Probably I didn't think enough about the code. I suspected that in some cases the expression `x * 100 + 0.5` might result in an inexact/unexpected result that might be avoided. But sure, if you are using `double` for representing decimal numbers you should expect such surprises.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [round() for float in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c) which talks about rounding floats although not to 2 places.  The same basic techniques should work.