# How do you round off decimal places in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

I need help rounding off a float value to one decimal place.

I know `setprecision(x)` and `cout << precision(x)`. Both of which work if I wanted to round the entire float, but I am only interested in rounding the decimals to the tenths place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rounding to the second decimal spot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030190/rounding-to-the-second-decimal-spot)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's another solution which doesn't require casting to int:

```
#include <cmath>

y = floor(x * 10d) / 10d
```

Answer (score 8):

```
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    float f1 = 3.14159f;
    float f2 = 3.49321f;
    std::cout << std::floor(f1 * 10 + 0.5) / 10 << std::endl; 
    std::cout << std::floor(f2 * 10 + 0.5) / 10 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::round(f1 * 10) / 10 << std::endl; // C++11
    std::cout << std::round(f2 * 10) / 10 << std::endl; // C++11
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
int main()
{

    float a = 4212.12345f;
    float b = a * 10.0f;
    float c = ((int)b) / 10.0f;

    cout << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```