# C++ printing strange behave

Tags: c++, printf

I have a C++ problem:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double k = 1.2366;
    cout << printf("%.3lf\n", k);
}
```

the output is:

```
1.237
6
```

but I expect:

```
1.237
```

why do i get this additional 6 at the 2nd line ?

Comment: because printf returns 6

Comment: Typically you don't want to use `cout` *and* `printf` on one line. Pick one. In this case, since you seem to want numerical formatting, just remove `cout <<` from that line and it should work. Alternatively, remove the `printf` portion and pull in the iomanip header.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you first call `printf` that prints out the number and then stream the result of `printf` (the number of characters printed) to `cout`.

Comment: how can i avoid that and also print 1.237 as a result

Comment: Use either `printf("%.3f", k)` by itself, or include `<iomanip>` and use `cout << fixed << setprecision(3) << k`

Comment: Uh well, yes, stick to one method. Either use `printf` or use `iomanip` like @AlexYan said.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `printf` returns the number of printed characters. To get your code right, simply use `std::cout` directly with the desired precision:

```
std::cout << fixed << setprecision(3);
std::cout << k << "\n";
```

If you want to round results, read [How do you round off decimal places in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103514/how-do-you-round-off-decimal-places-in-c) which points you to e.g. floor/ceil/round. But take care to not round the value itself, if you use it again.

Comment: cout<<k; obviously prints 1.2366 , at my question i wanted to print 1.237

Comment: i tried to do setpercision() but that doesnt round the number I need to return rounded number up to the third char after the floating point

Comment: Added a link to the corresponding question.

Comment: I'd suggest you to open a new question with proper formatting.