# Rounding down/truncating double

Tags: c++, double, point, floating

I'm doing calculations with financial data formatted as follows:

```
<up to 5 digits>.<two digits>
```

Basically, in my program I'm encountering a floating point error. For example, if I have:

```
11.09 - (11.09 * 0.005) = 11.03455
```

I want to be able to use `11.03455` and not what's generated: 11.0345499999999...

I'm comparing values that my program generates with values I have in text files that are in string format. I only need two decimal points of precision and I can round down. Is there a way that I can cut this to 11.03?

I was thinking it would be easiest if I turn this into a string and just parse it character by character, only adding two characters past the '.' character. Is this a good solution? Any better ideas?

Here is what I have:

```
string dataProcessor::createTwoDec(double price){
    string s = to_string(price);
    string output = "";
    int dist = 0;
    int num_wanted = 0;

    bool pt_found = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(s[i] == '.')
            pt_found = true;
        if(pt_found)
            dist++;
        if(dist > 3)
            break;
        output += s[i];
        num_wanted++;

    }
    return output.substr(0, num_wanted);
}
```

Comment: Maybe `round( value * 100.0 ) / 100.0;`?

Comment: *I'm doing calculations with financial data* --  I hope you're aware of the inexactness of floating point calculations, and why `double` may not be suitable to represent monetary values and calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formula for round-off by n decimal places (n is not too large):

```
round(x*10^n)/10^n
 where n is number of decimal places required.
```

In your case, n is 5. Hence, it will be

```
 result = round(result*100000)/100000;
```

See [How do you round off decimal places in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103514/how-do-you-round-off-decimal-places-in-c)

Comment: Let me try that and get back to you.