# Removing some digits after decimal point in C++

Tags: c++

I need to remove digits after decimal points but not all.

For Example, double dig=3.1459038585 i need to convert it to dig=3.14

I think i need to multiple dig to 100 then convert it to integer and then again convert to double and delete to 100 (All this will be 1 line). But is there any function to do this faster?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030190/rounding-to-the-second-decimal-spot

Comment: its for printing, i wanted to write PS for such answers. I need to remove digits and use new digits in calculations.

Comment: @devnull that question is about formatting output, not about internal processing.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Doesn't it list both options -- round & truncate to a given number of decimal places?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4030321/2235132

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    double d = 3.1459038585;
    std::cout << std::floor(d * 100.) / 100. << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: This is actually incorrect since it won't deal with negatives properly. It will return -3.15 if you flip the sign on your d. Niels's version is (almost) correct

Comment: @Corvin: That is a common misconception. [There are many different types of rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking). The above way is just showing one style of rounding, which may or may not fit your use case.

Answer (score 10):

Any function that implements this functionality will be more flexible, and as such slower by definition. So yes, just write this:

```
double truncated = (double)((int)dig*100)/100;
```

It's all CPU-native operations any way so it'll barely cost any clock cycles, especially if inlined or used as a macro.

Comment: Correct but one small typo. It should be (double)((int)(dig*100))/100 - note the parentheses after (int). Otherwise dig is converted (truncated) before it is multiplied