# Error in extracting digits from integer

Tags: c++, math, int

I have a simple program which gives the wrong output, the expected output is the digits of the number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int n = 125521;
   int d = floor(log10(n));
   printf("%d Digits\n",d+1);
   int t =0;
   while(floor(log10(n))-t)
   { printf("%d-----%d\n",(n/(int)pow(10,floor(log10(n))-t)%10),t); t++;}
   return 0;
}
```

This gives the output

```
6 Digits
1-----0
2-----1
5-----2
7-----3
2-----4
```

Strange output. Why does 7 come ?

I know how to get the digits by other ways but I want this solution to work.

Now as suggested in the answers I get rid of the bug in the while loop (>=0)
and I get the output:

[image]

Comment: [check this](http://ideone.com/Dw8a22) its your output.

Comment: @SouravKanta Why do I get wrong output in my CodeBlocks MingW ? This is very bad error.

Comment: I have no idea.Pls wait someone who is better at c will tell you.Ideone gives you right output.

Comment: Do you like reading code that scrunched up?  It is really hard to read.

Comment: Don't use `pow`, `log10`,  or floating point for this — it's not exact. You need only `/` and `%`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: I get 1, 2, 5, 5, 2 in the first column of digits.  I'm using GCC 5.1.0 on Mac OS X 10.10.3, compiling in 64-bit mode.  What are you using to get the 7?

Comment: what are the reasons you want to use the super slow log and pow instead of simple division?

Comment: @adrian008 There is no guarantee that `pow(10, whatever)` will give you an exact answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5

Comment: @molbdnilo yes I know that, using / and % its easier also. But I wanted this way to see one more way.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am using GCC 4.8.1

Comment: On which O/S? What hardware?  Again, on my Mac, using GCC 4.8.1 in 64-bit compilation mode (Intel CPU, Mac/BSD maths library), I get the expected 1,2,5,5,2 as the output. Also when compiled in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Maybe you should print more information to debug what's going on.  Print various intermediate expressions to see if you can spot where the 7 comes from.  As I noted, I can't reproduce it on my machine.  It seems improbable that it was produced, but if you've got the evidence it happened, there must be an explanation.  You aren't using a Pentium 4 chip, are you?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The link I pointed out shows a question where `pow` can have issues.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Off-by-one is not wholly implausible (a little unlikely, but not implausible).  Off-by-two is rather less likely.  I'm curious to know which platform is showing such bad behaviour on arithmetic in the relatively ordinary range of numbers (there's nothing extraordinary about values in the range of 6-digit numbers, unless someone is forcing `float` (32-bit floating point) calculations on the code somehow).

Comment: Have you tried finding out which of the many chained expressions there is giving a faulty result? Taking the thing apart for analysis is the first thing that a programmer would do. Also, it makes the code more readable; As it stands, from the mere presentation it wouldn't pass any code review.

Comment: Silly question time: have you printed `n` in your code?  What happens when you do?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes it is printing fine.

Answer (score 1):

Put proper spaces `(n/(int)pow(10,floor(log10(n))-t)%10)` in this line.

So many redundant call of `floor(log10(n))`.

`while loop` will *loop* less than `1` from digit numbers.

I have no idea, why you print `t` besides digits, say:

```
1-----0
2-----1
     ^^^
```

[Can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/JuXWUY) what you said.

Are you looking for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 550052111;
    int d = floor(log10(n));
    printf("%d Digits\n", d + 1);
    int t = 0;
    int power, divition, mod;
    int digitCount[10] = {0};
    while (d +1 - t) {
        power = (int) pow(10, d - t);
        divition = n / power;
        mod = divition % 10;
        digitCount[mod]++;
        t++;
    }

    for (t= 0; t < 10; t++) {
        if(digitCount[t]) {
            printf("%d-----%d\n", t, digitCount[t]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
9 Digits
0-----2
1-----3
2-----1
5-----3
```

**Caution:** input `n` must not overflow *Integer*. To find the digit counts in a number, you do not need `floor`, `pow` or `log10`, only `/` and `%` is sufficient.

Comment: I know the solution, i wanted to solve by the method i used.

Comment: @adrian008, which method? Look, in the `printf` function what you do, I do the same buy using different variable to see whether they produce right values or not. Say `1/0 ` can crash your program.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, mistake, just copied and paste, that's why `t` came by, typo.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in your while loop.

```
while(floor(log10(n))-t)
```

Should be

```
while(0 <= floor(log10(n))-t)
```

The index in your case should start from 0 rather than 1.

Fix that bug and you should get the proper output as follows:

```
6 Digits
1-----0
2-----1
5-----2
5-----3
2-----4
1-----5
```

Comment: You could also write `while (t <= floor(log10(n)))` which would be clearer still, and `while (t <= d)` to be simpler.  This does not explain why the OP sees a 7 instead of the second 5, though.  It does explain why they don't see the final 1, but that isn't officially part of the question.

Comment: Yeah, **while ( t <= d)** is a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

To find out why you are getting the 7 instead of the 5, you need to do some serious diagnostic printing — maybe using code something like this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 125521;
    int d = floor(log10(n));
    printf("n = %d: %d Digits\n", n, d + 1);
    int t = 0;
    while (floor(log10(n)) >= t)
    {
        printf("t = %d: n = %d; L = log10(n) = %f; F = floor(L) = %f\n",
                t, n, log10(n), floor(log10(n)));
        printf("       T = F-t = %f;", floor(log10(n)) - t);
        printf(" P = pow(10,T)= %f\n", pow(10, floor(log10(n)) - t));
        printf("       I = (int)P = %d; D = n/I = %d; M = D %% 10 = %d\n",
               (int)pow(10, floor(log10(n)) - t),
               n / (int)pow(10, floor(log10(n)) - t),
               n / (int)pow(10, floor(log10(n)) - t) % 10);
        printf("%d-----%d\n", (n / (int)pow(10, floor(log10(n)) - t) % 10), t);
        t++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've modified the loop condition; the old-style Fortran II arithmetic `if` condition really isn't good style in C.  It also prints the last digit.  It would be better if the loop were written `for (int t = 0; t <= d; t++)`, but I've not made that change.

On a Mac running OS X 10.10.3, using GCC 5.1.0 compiling a 64-bit program, the result is:

```
n = 125521: 6 Digits
t = 0: n = 125521; L = log10(n) = 5.098716; F = floor(L) = 5.000000
       T = F-t = 5.000000; P = pow(10,T)= 100000.000000
       I = (int)P = 100000; D = n/I = 1; M = D % 10 = 1
1-----0
t = 1: n = 125521; L = log10(n) = 5.098716; F = floor(L) = 5.000000
       T = F-t = 4.000000; P = pow(10,T)= 10000.000000
       I = (int)P = 10000; D = n/I = 12; M = D % 10 = 2
2-----1
t = 2: n = 125521; L = log10(n) = 5.098716; F = floor(L) = 5.000000
       T = F-t = 3.000000; P = pow(10,T)= 1000.000000
       I = (int)P = 1000; D = n/I = 125; M = D % 10 = 5
5-----2
t = 3: n = 125521; L = log10(n) = 5.098716; F = floor(L) = 5.000000
       T = F-t = 2.000000; P = pow(10,T)= 100.000000
       I = (int)P = 100; D = n/I = 1255; M = D % 10 = 5
5-----3
t = 4: n = 125521; L = log10(n) = 5.098716; F = floor(L) = 5.000000
       T = F-t = 1.000000; P = pow(10,T)= 10.000000
       I = (int)P = 10; D = n/I = 12552; M = D % 10 = 2
2-----4
t = 5: n = 125521; L = log10(n) = 5.098716; F = floor(L) = 5.000000
       T = F-t = 0.000000; P = pow(10,T)= 1.000000
       I = (int)P = 1; D = n/I = 125521; M = D % 10 = 1
1-----5
```

You should run either this program or something very similar and show the results of the intermediate calculations.  We can then, maybe, begin to understand why you see a 7 instead of a 5.