# Adding to an int alters a separate char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, wav, binary-data

I am trying to parse a .wav file header. If I remove the `chunk_size +=...` line, i get the expect result: `RIFF`, but once I add that line, I get `RIFFÄÿÿÿ`. Why is every value added  to `chunk_size` apparently "appended" to `chunk_id`? How can `chunk_id` have more than four elements? Is there something basic about arrays or binary data that I don't understand? Is it inappropriate to use `cout` on a char array?

```
struct Wave
{
    Wave (FILE* file) {
        char header[44];
        uint size = fread(header, sizeof(char), 44, file);
        chunk_size = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
            chunk_id[i] = header[i];
            chunk_size += header[i + 4] * pow(16, i);
        }
        cout << chunk_id;
    }
    char chunk_id[4];
    uint chunk_size;
    char format[4];
    ...
    ...
    ...
};
```

Comment: The thing you don't appear to quite understand is how `cout << chunk_id` works.  You seem to have arrays and binary data mostly fine.

Comment: The file was opened in binary mode, I presume?

Comment: `pow(16, i);` -- This is not guaranteed to work as you expect it to:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout << chunk_id;
```

works only when `chunk_id` is null terminated. Since it is not in your program, the program has undefined behavior.

Make `chunk_id` an array of 5 elements and make sure to null terminate it in the constructor.

```
Wave (FILE* file) {
    char header[44];
    uint size = fread(header, sizeof(char), 44, file);
    chunk_size = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
        chunk_id[i] = header[i];
        chunk_size += header[i + 4] * pow(16, i);
    }
    chunk_id[4] = '\0';
    cout << chunk_id;
}
char chunk_id[5];
```

Comment: You should probably explain how to fix the issue, which should be pretty straightforward for this case.

Comment: So there isn't anything wrong with `chunk_id` itself, just with the way I'm attempting to view it?

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thanks for your quick response and clear explanation.

Comment: Possible pitfalls include `chunk_id[i]` being `0`, or `'\n'`.  (`cout` is a text stream). `cout.write(chunk_id, 4);` would have been another way (which does deal with the `0` issue but not the newline)