# C2264 Error when pushing back an object to vector

Tags: c++, vector

Hey guys I was working on a board game and implementing its table till I got this error.

```
class Grid {
private:
    int     size;
    char**  grid;
    int noofsupplies; //determined by the grid size.
    vector<Food*> food;
    vector<Water*>  water; //Used 4 different vector to keep track of every kind of object easier.
    vector<Mine*> mine;
    vector<Medical*> medical;
public:
    Grid(int sizeofgrid) {
        size = sizeofgrid;
        noofsupplies = 3 * (pow(sizeofgrid, 2) / 25);
        grid = new char*[size];
        for (int i = 0;i < size;i++)
            grid[i] = new char[size];
        for (int i = 0;i < size;i++) {
            for (int j = 0;j < size;j++)
                grid[i][j] = '-';
        }
        Resources* f = new Food();
        Resources* w = new Water();
        Resources* m = new Mine();
        Resources* s = new Medical();
        for (int i = 0;i < noofsupplies;i++) {
            food.push_back(*f);
            water.push_back(*w);
            mine.push_back(*m);
            medical.push_back(*s);
        }

        deploy_resources(); //place the food inside the map..
    }
```

But it gives the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
>   (active)      no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty,
>   _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=Food *, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list

What can be the reason?

Comment: already tried it didnt work :(

Comment: Those are vectors of pointers...

Comment: `vector<Food*> food;` expects you to `push_back` a `Food *`. `*f` is a `Food`, not a `Food *`. If you `push_back` `f` then that line will work.

Comment: @AlexD but Resources is an abstract class for my food water mine and medicals so i should use it when defining a new resource then specify the type..

Comment: On another note: avoid `new`, you have memory leaks everywhere and there is no reason to use pointers. It makes much more sense to use `vector<Food> food; Food f; food.push_back(f);`

Comment: `(pow(sizeofgrid, 2) / 25);`  Do not use `pow` to compute integer powers.  [There is no guarantee you will get the desired results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5/25678721#25678721)

Comment: @nwp But as I said above resources is my abstract class shouldnt i use it when creating a new object of type abstract class ?

Comment: @nwp Actually the type of `f` is `Resource*` and the type of `*f` is `Resource&`.  The vector's won't accept it either unless `Resource` is a subclass of `Food`, `Water`, `Mine`, and `Medical`.

Comment: @BallsyCoder Your code has memory leaks.  You lose the pointer values returned to you from `new`, thus never getting the chance to free the memory.

Answer (score 2):

`food` is a vector of pointers to `Food`, not a vector of `Resources` objects.

You can do this:

```
        Food* f = new Food();
        Water* w = new Water();
        Mine* m = new Mine();
        Medical* s = new Medical();
        for (int i = 0;i < noofsupplies;i++) {
            food.push_back(f);
            water.push_back(w);
            mine.push_back(m);
            medical.push_back(s);
        }
```

But you are just putting `noofsupplies` different copies of the same pointer, pointing to the same object. You can get the same effect by just doing

```
food.insert(food.begin(), noofsupplies, f);
water.insert(water.begin(), noofsupplies, w);
mine.insert(mine.begin(), noofsupplies, m);
medical.insert(medical.begin(), noofsupplies, s);
```

instead of the loop.

But having the same object many times is probably not what you want. If they should all be different objects, have your loop do

```
        for (int i = 0; i < noofsupplies; i++) {
            food.push_back(new Food());
            water.push_back(new Water());
            mine.push_back(new Mine());
            medical.push_back(new Medical());
        }
```

Or, if they don't need to be pointers at all, just have `vector<Food>`, etc., instead of vectors of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `push_back()` calls are not pushing the correct values that the various `vector`s are expecting.

`vector<Food*>` expects you to `push_back()` a `Food*` but you are trying to push a `Resource*` instead.

`vector<Water*>` expects you to `push_back()` a `Water*` but you are trying to push a `Resource*` instead.

`vector<Mine*>` expects you to `push_back()` a `Mine*` but you are trying to push a `Resource*` instead.

`vector<Medical*>` expects you to `push_back()` a `Mine*` but you are trying to push a `Resource*` instead.

Yes, you are creating objects of type `Food`, `Water`, `Mine` and `Medical`, respectively.  But you are assigning all of them to `Resource*` variables, and that is where the error is originating from.  None of your `vector`s are expecting `Resource*`.

Try this instead:

```
class Grid {
private:
    int size;
    char** grid;
    int noofsupplies; //determined by the grid size.
    vector<Food*> food;
    vector<Water*> water;
    vector<Mine*> mine;
    vector<Medical*> medical;
public:
    Grid(int sizeofgrid)
        : size(0), grid(NULL), noofsupplies(0)
    {
        size = sizeofgrid;
        noofsupplies = 3 * ((sizeofgrid * sizeofgrid) / 25);
        grid = new char*[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size;i++)
            grid[i] = new char[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
                grid[i][j] = '-';
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < noofsupplies; ++i) {
            food.push_back(new Food);
            water.push_back(new Water);
            mine.push_back(new Mine);
            medical.push_back(new Medical);
        }

        deploy_resources(); //place the food inside the map..
    }

    Grid(const Grid &src)
        : size(0), grid(NULL), noofsupplies(0)
    {
        size = src.size;
        noofsupplies = src.noofsupplies;
        grid = new char*[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            grid[i] = new char[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
                grid[i][j] = src.grid[i][j];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < noofsupplies; ++i) {
            food.push_back(new Food(*(src.food[i])));
            water.push_back(new Water(*(src.water[i])));
            mine.push_back(new Mine(*(src.mine[i])));
            medical.push_back(new Medical(*(src.Medical[i])));
        }

        deploy_resources(); //place the food inside the map..
    }

    ~Grid() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            delete[] grid[i];
        delete[] grid;
        for (int i = 0; i < noofsupplies; ++i) {
            delete food[i];
            delete water[i];
            delete mine[i];
            delete medical[i];
        }
    }

    Grid& operator=(Grid rhs) {
        swap(*this, rhs);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Which can be *greatly* simplified by getting rid of all the `new` and `delete` calls, let the compiler and STL handle all of the memory allocations and releases for you:

```
class Grid {
private:
    vector<vector<char> > grid;
    vector<Food> food;
    vector<Water> water;
    vector<Mine> mine;
    vector<Medical> medical;
public:
    Grid(int sizeofgrid) {
        grid.resize(sizeofgrid);
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeofgrid; ++i)
            grid[i].assign(sizeofgrid, '-');

        int noofsupplies = 3 * ((sizeofgrid * sizeofgrid) / 25);
        food.resize(noofsupplies);
        water.resize(noofsupplies);
        mine.resize(noofsupplies);
        medical.resize(noofsupplies);

        deploy_resources(); //place the food inside the map..
    }
};
```

Comment: "you are trying to push a `Resource*` instead." - he pushed `*f`, so `Resource`