# Given all numbers between 0 and 10^9 and its reverse, how many numbers are mixed, odd and even?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, math, analysis

The next statement is the problem for an exercise.

[image]

I did this solution. It's executing a loop from 0 to 10^9. But it's taking many time for being executed. So, the next step which I thought is add a hashmap into the result between the number and its reverse as keys, saving the result.

But the program is still consuming time. I guess I'm missing maybe a math theory or another approach to solve time in less time.

Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int reverseNumber(int n) {
    int reverse = 0;

    while (n > 0) {
        reverse = reverse * 10;
        reverse += n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
    }

    return reverse;
}

string isNumberEvenOddOrMixed(int n) {
    bool even = false;
    bool odd = false;

    while (n > 0) {
        int rem = n % 10;
        n = n / 10;

        if (rem % 2 == 0)
            even = true;
        else
            odd = true;
    }

    return even && odd ? "Mixed" : (even ? "Even" : "Odd");
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int even = 0, odd = 0, mixed = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < pow(10, 9); i++) {
        // Verify if i already exists in the hashmap,
        // if it is, just print the value saved.

        int nReversed = reverseNumber(i);
        int sum = i + nReversed;
        string result = isNumberEvenOddOrMixed(sum);


        if (result == "Even") even++;
        else if (result == "Odd") odd++;
        else mixed++;

        // Save i and nReversed in a hashmap with the result
        // hashmap[i] = result;
        // hashmap[nReversed] = result;

        cout << i << " + " <<  nReversed << " = " << sum << " : " << result << "\n";
    }

    cout << "Even: " << even << "\n";
    cout << "Odd: " << odd << "\n";
    cout << "Mixed: " << mixed << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

These are the results from 0 to 10^2. I just printed to see the relationship between the numbers:

```
0 + 0 = 0 : Odd
1 + 1 = 2 : Even
2 + 2 = 4 : Even
3 + 3 = 6 : Even
4 + 4 = 8 : Even
5 + 5 = 10 : Mixed
6 + 6 = 12 : Mixed
7 + 7 = 14 : Mixed
8 + 8 = 16 : Mixed
9 + 9 = 18 : Mixed
10 + 1 = 11 : Odd
11 + 11 = 22 : Even
12 + 21 = 33 : Odd
13 + 31 = 44 : Even
14 + 41 = 55 : Odd
15 + 51 = 66 : Even
16 + 61 = 77 : Odd
17 + 71 = 88 : Even
18 + 81 = 99 : Odd
19 + 91 = 110 : Mixed
20 + 2 = 22 : Even
21 + 12 = 33 : Odd
22 + 22 = 44 : Even
23 + 32 = 55 : Odd
24 + 42 = 66 : Even
25 + 52 = 77 : Odd
26 + 62 = 88 : Even
27 + 72 = 99 : Odd
28 + 82 = 110 : Mixed
29 + 92 = 121 : Mixed
30 + 3 = 33 : Odd
31 + 13 = 44 : Even
32 + 23 = 55 : Odd
33 + 33 = 66 : Even
34 + 43 = 77 : Odd
35 + 53 = 88 : Even
36 + 63 = 99 : Odd
37 + 73 = 110 : Mixed
38 + 83 = 121 : Mixed
39 + 93 = 132 : Mixed
40 + 4 = 44 : Even
41 + 14 = 55 : Odd
42 + 24 = 66 : Even
43 + 34 = 77 : Odd
44 + 44 = 88 : Even
45 + 54 = 99 : Odd
46 + 64 = 110 : Mixed
47 + 74 = 121 : Mixed
48 + 84 = 132 : Mixed
49 + 94 = 143 : Mixed
50 + 5 = 55 : Odd
51 + 15 = 66 : Even
52 + 25 = 77 : Odd
53 + 35 = 88 : Even
54 + 45 = 99 : Odd
55 + 55 = 110 : Mixed
56 + 65 = 121 : Mixed
57 + 75 = 132 : Mixed
58 + 85 = 143 : Mixed
59 + 95 = 154 : Mixed
60 + 6 = 66 : Even
61 + 16 = 77 : Odd
62 + 26 = 88 : Even
63 + 36 = 99 : Odd
64 + 46 = 110 : Mixed
65 + 56 = 121 : Mixed
66 + 66 = 132 : Mixed
67 + 76 = 143 : Mixed
68 + 86 = 154 : Mixed
69 + 96 = 165 : Mixed
70 + 7 = 77 : Odd
71 + 17 = 88 : Even
72 + 27 = 99 : Odd
73 + 37 = 110 : Mixed
74 + 47 = 121 : Mixed
75 + 57 = 132 : Mixed
76 + 67 = 143 : Mixed
77 + 77 = 154 : Mixed
78 + 87 = 165 : Mixed
79 + 97 = 176 : Mixed
80 + 8 = 88 : Even
81 + 18 = 99 : Odd
82 + 28 = 110 : Mixed
83 + 38 = 121 : Mixed
84 + 48 = 132 : Mixed
85 + 58 = 143 : Mixed
86 + 68 = 154 : Mixed
87 + 78 = 165 : Mixed
88 + 88 = 176 : Mixed
89 + 98 = 187 : Mixed
90 + 9 = 99 : Odd
91 + 19 = 110 : Mixed
92 + 29 = 121 : Mixed
93 + 39 = 132 : Mixed
94 + 49 = 143 : Mixed
95 + 59 = 154 : Mixed
96 + 69 = 165 : Mixed
97 + 79 = 176 : Mixed
98 + 89 = 187 : Mixed
99 + 99 = 198 : Mixed
Even: 24
Odd: 26
Mixed: 50
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < pow(10, 9); i++) `  -- You are calling `pow()` multiple times for no reason whatsoever.  In addition, it returns a `double`, not an int, plus `pow` is not guaranteed to give you an exact answer, even if you're using integer.  3 strikes, your out.  Just put `for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)` or similar.

Comment: Also, you have multiple tags.  Please choose a language.  In any event, why is your function that determines what type of number it is returning a `string`?  That takes time constructing and destroying that returned string.  Just return an `int` denoting the type, not a string.  You're also comparing strings to "Even", "Odd", etc.  taking up time.  There should be **no** string usage at all in this program, except to output the results.

Comment: Also, in your function to determine if the number is odd or even, if both odd and even flags are `true`, return right away that the number is mixed.  There is no need to keep looping through the number if both flags happen to be true.

Comment: Why do you say that `0` is `Odd`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: That first reason is premature optimization (why optimize manually what a compiler optimizes automatically?), the last is rather theoretical as `double` has enough precision.

Comment: you need to print all 10^9 result out ? or just the count of odd , even , mixed result?

Comment: @shole just count odd, even and mixed result

Comment: @oscar.fimbres why i am asking is that, if you want to speed up, then printing out all solution is impossible as I/O time itself is already O(10^9). While if you only need to count the result, I am thinking there maybe some DP solution / combinatorics can help

Comment: @oscar.fimbres Also I do not understand why this question has so many downvotes..I think it is a not-so-easy problem and you have posted your code, elaborate on the question, etc....

Comment: @shole yeah, also I was thinking that might be an performance issue (printing). What do you mean when you say combinatorics or DP?

Comment: @oscar.fimbres hard to explain in comments, you can just Google them. DP stands for dynamic programming (not disney princess).

Comment: @oscar.fimbres You don't need to check all possible value, but part of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to count odd, even and mixed result, you should be able to find the result by calculate 1111111192 records (about 1/10th of total) for [0, 10^9)

---

**Solution Idea**

For 0 to 9, just calculate it all.

For remaining values, think as below. you don't need to build the table, but use the concept.

1. Setup a table for value of same number of digits (let number of digit be r)

   - size: 9 column with 10^(r-1) row
   - value distribution: Top left corner is the smallest of that digit part, plus one when moving down, plus 10^(r-1) when moving right

> 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
>
> 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91
>
> 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82 92
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89 99

2. Looking at this table, you will observe the result of any value will be same as the result as the one on its top right position (upward by 1 and right by 1).
3. In this sense, you should be able to see for digit r table, **the count can be calculated by looking up result of values on first column and last row and then for each result calculated times a correct counter** (number of values in its diagonal in point 2, values between 1 to 9)

   - (result of 10) * 1
   - (result of 11) * 2
   - (result of 12) * 3
   - (result of 13) * 4
   - (result of 14) * 5
   - (result of 15) * 6
   - (result of 16) * 7
   - (result of 17) * 8
   - (result of 18) * 9
   - (result of 19) * 9
   - (result of 29) * 8
   - (result of 39) * 7
   - (result of 49) * 6
   - (result of 59) * 5
   - (result of 69) * 4
   - (result of 79) * 3
   - (result of 89) * 2
   - (result of 99) * 1

counter distribution: 1 at top left, increase counter by 1 when moving down till 9 is reached. 1 at bottom right, increase counter by 1 when moving left.

---

**Prove**

Assume you have a value 'abcdefg' and ('a' not equal to 1 and 'bcdefg' not equal to 0).
Under this condition, top right position of 'abcdefg' in above table should exist.

> Rewrite 'abcdefg' as a*10^(r-1) + b*10^(r-2) + c*10^(r-3) + ... + f*10
>   + g
>
> Reverse of 'abcdefg' is g*10^(r-1) + f*10^(r-2) + e*10^(r-3) + ... +
>   b*10 + a
>
> **Calculated value of 'abcdefg' is (a+g)*10^(r-1) + (b+f)*10^(r-2) +
>   (c+e)*10^(r-3) + ... + (f+b)*10 + (g+a)**

The value in top right position of 'abcdefg' is 'abcdefg' + 10^(r-1) - 1. We  can write it as 'a"bcdefg"' where a" = a+1 and g" = g-1

> Rewrite 'a"bcdefg"' as a"*10^(r-1) + b*10^(r-2) + c*10^(r-3) + ... +
>   f*10 + g"
>
> Reverse of 'a"bcdefg"' is g"*10^(r-1) + f*10^(r-2) + e*10^(r-3) + ...
>   + b*10 + a"
>
> Calculated value of 'a"bcdefg"' is (a"+g")*10^(r-1) + (b+f)*10^(r-2) +
>   (c+e)*10^(r-3) + ... + (f+b)*10 + (g"+a")
>
> Since g"+a" = g-1 + a+1 = g+a, we have **calculated value of 'a"bcdefg"'
>   is (a+g)*10^(r-1) + (b+f)*10^(r-2) + (c+e)*10^(r-3) + ... + (f+b)*10
>   + (g+a)** and **is equal to calculated value of 'abcdefg'**

This prove that the calculated value will be same as the calculated value of its top right element

Comment: Thanks for wise response. I'm surprised how you quickly could arrive to this good solution. I did the sample with r = 2. Just for the case when r = 3, so if I understand well, it's necessary to calculate the numbers from 100 to 199 (incrementing 1) and then 199 (incrementing 100), right?

Comment: @oscar.fimbres Yes, it is correct for the case when r=3.One simple way is to generate some number of continuous sample and then look for a repeating pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of small optimisation ideas:

1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pow(10, 9); i++)
```

This loop is recalculating 10^9 every time. Just do it once and store it in a const variable

2.

I would change the "isNumberEvenOddOrMixed" function to return an enumeration value instead of a string. It will gain you a small increase in performance not having to compare, create and destroy strings.

Comment: The `pow` doesn't even need to be called at all, plus it has the potential to give wrong results.  See [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5/25678721#25678721)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't really mean to imply that he should use pow at all - just that he should calculate the result before hand, but I can see I wasn't clear.