# Why is this loop outputting 0 every time to sqdNumber_result?

Tags: c++, loops, integer

I am trying to find the sum of each digit in an integer squared, and for any integer that is input to sqdnumber, it outputs 0 to sqdNumber_result, and I can't figure out why.

Also, this is through edX, but I have been stuck for a week or so on this problem, and I have looked at a lot of different topics, but haven't found anything of use to me.

I used codeblocks to write this, but the system testing it uses codeboard

```
void squaredSum(int sqdnumber,int &sqdNumber_result) {
for (int i=1; i>1; i++){
    if (sqdnumber >= ((10^(i-1))-1)){
        int rem = (sqdnumber % (10^i));
        int rem1 = (sqdnumber % (10^(i-1)));
        int temp = (rem - rem1);
        sqdNumber_result = sqdNumber_result + (temp^2);
    }

    else{
        break;
    }
}
}
```

I am new to coding, and just learning to do loops in C++.

This is the first iteration of the loop I have gotten their system to actually give me an output for it(I've written and rewritten it 20 or so times), but it isn't giving me an output that makes sense.

I wouldn't ask but I am at my wit's end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, `^` is the [xor operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/xor), not the nth power. for that, you should use [pow](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow).

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of this, to use the pow function I need to use     #include<math.h> correct?

Comment: @JamesChristie, if this answers the question it's polite to accept it as the answer.

Comment: Or you just multiply that value by itself... Which I'm guessing will be faster than the more general `pow()` function.

Answer (score 3):

The for statement does not loop. The condition is false the first iteration

Comment: Note to OP: This would be super easy to see by running a debugger and stepping through the function.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

```
for (int i=1; i>1; i++){
```

This loop will not loop at all, since the condition `i>1` is never met.

---

The second issue is the usage of `^` to do a power operation.  The `^` in C++ is not a power operator, it is the `exclusive-or` operator.

So the answer at first glance would be to use the `std::pow` function to compute powers.  However there can be drawbacks using it if the exponent is an integer.  The reason is that `pow` is **not** guaranteed to work perfectly for integer powers.

See this as to [dangers of using pow() for integral exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5/25678721#25678721)

It is advised to just use a simple array of values with the powers of 10 and doing a lookup.

Answer (score -3):

you said you were new to C++ so I tried to get a solution without using the for loop and tried to make it as simple as I could.
Let me know if this was any help.

```
//Code to calculate the sum of each digit squared//
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int integer1,integer2,sum, square;

    cout<<"Please enter two integers"<<endl;

    cin>>integer1>>integer2 ;

    cout<<"The sum of your integers is"<<" "<<endl;

    sum = (integer1+integer2);

    cout<<sum<<endl;

    cout<<"The square of your sum is"<<" "<<endl;

    square = (sum*sum);

    cout<<square<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the explanation for "Why is this loop outputting 0 every time to sqdNumber_result?" is where? Your answer seems to be totally unrelated.