# which data type to use in C and Java for calculating the modulo inverse of a number?

Tags: java, c

I went through the below mentioned tutorial and I tried calculating the modulo inverse of the number in C as well as in Java but in both cases , I am getting the output as 0 ,please guide me in my correcting my code .

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/math/number-theory/multiplicative-inverse/tutorial/

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
       Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
       int a=sc.nextInt();
       BigInteger bi=BigInteger.valueOf(a);
       BigInteger k = new BigDecimal(Math.pow(10,9)).toBigInteger();
       BigInteger b=k.add(BigInteger.valueOf(7));
       BigInteger c=b.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
       BigInteger m=bi.modPow(c,BigInteger.valueOf(1));
       BigInteger d=m.mod(b);
       System.out.println(d);

    }
}
```

In C ,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<inttypes.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    uintmax_t a;
    scanf(" %ju",&a);
    uintmax_t b=pow(10,9);
    uintmax_t m=b+7;
    uintmax_t c=((uintmax_t)pow(a,m-2))%(m);
    printf("%ju",c);
    return 0;
}
```

I am unable to get the reason behind the overflow here ,please clarify this .

Comment: There is no `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` in C.  If you want arbitrary sized integers, you need to write the code yourself or use an add-on library.   Needless to say, any "hackerrank" question that requires integers that go beyond 64-bit are better solved in languages that have support for these types, and `C` is not one of those languages.  Also, [do not use pow() if your exponent is an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os)

Comment: I'd wager the reason for the overflow is here: `((uintmax_t)pow(a,m-2))` any `a > 1` will be unimaginably large if raised to the power of `10^9`, and certainly larger than the largest number representable by an `uintmax_t`.

Comment: pow() function is double type, result maybe is OK in integer context, maybe not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your java code does not work is that

```
BigInteger m=bi.modPow(c,BigInteger.valueOf(1));
```

calculates `bi^c mod 1`, which is 0 for any `bi` and `c`.

What you want to calculate is `bi^c mod b`, which is coded as

```
BigInteger m = bi.modPow(c, b);
```

---

Since C does not have a `powmod` function you need to program it yourself.

The following function calculates `x^e mod m`:

```
uintmax_t powmod(uintmax_t x, uintmax_t e, uintmax_t m) {
    uintmax_t result = 1;
    while (e > 0) {
        if (e&1) {
            result = result * x % m;
        }
        x = x * x % m;
        e >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @user123 I've added a powmod function for C

Comment: I am unable to understand the point if (e&1) {
            result = result * x % m;
        }                                                                                                                     It means that if exponent is odd then result=result*x%m , couldn't get this point .

Comment: I have written the function for calculating powmod ,plz check still I am not getting the desired output :                                                                                http://codepad.org/w1L4z7L4

Comment: You are using `unsigned long` which is too small for the intermediate results (`x*x` and function result times `x`), so you have to use `unsigned long long` or `uintmax_t`. And please beware that `(x%m )* function((x*x)%m, (n-1)/2)` might be greater than `m`. @user123