# Something wrong with assigning the value of the equation to a variable

Tags: c++

The assignment of the value of the equation to the variable (second line inside the loop) is always less by 1 -on the first iteration only- although the equation (first line inside the loop) on its own calculates fine.

I am using MinGW compiler, codeLite software on a Windows machine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> elements_of_num {5, 0, 3};
    size_t power = 2;
    int n {0};
    for(int el: elements_of_num){
        std::cout << n + el * pow(10, power) << std::endl;
        n = n + el * pow(10, power);
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
        power--;
    }
    std::cin >> n;
    return 0;
}
```

> Expected result: {500, 500} {499, 499} {503, 503}
>
> Actual result: {500, 499} {499, 499} {502, 502}

Comment: [cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MyeIsEAZcHcty7Q5)

Comment: Something is wrong with your environment, not your code. The expected result is: 500, 500, 500, 500, 503, 503.

Comment: [Why pow(10,5) = 9,999 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9704195/995714), [Why a+=b*pow(10,c-i-1) == 99 c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39756656/995714), [Why does pow(n,2) return 24 when n=5, with my compiler and OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25678481/995714), [Why does gcc compiler output pow(10,2) as 99 not 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25474351/995714)...

Comment: it's a bad idea to use `pow` to calculate values from digits like that. Just iterate in reverse and then use `n = n*10 + el` which is much faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your pow implementation is inaccurate for these values. I have managed to get the same results as you by forcefully making `pow(10, power)` inaccurate.

In case of the first variant in your code:

> ```
> std::cout << n + el * pow(10, power) << std::endl;
> ```

The value of the expression is slightly less than 500. You can verify this by

```
 std::cout.precision(20);
 std::cout << n + el * pow(10, power) << std::endl;
```

I suspect that this will print something like:

```
499.99999499999995578
```

(Note that since your original code prints numbers with a lower precision, you are deceived to believe that the expression results with 500. However, the actual value is slightly smaller).

In the case of the second line of code:

```
n = n + el * pow(10, power);
```

the `499.99999499999995578` is assigned to an `int` variable, truncating the fraction and leaving you with 499. Everything goes south after that.

NOTE:

I don't think that [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) dictates how `pow(10, 2)` should be implemented, and in theory it can be implemented using e<sup>ln(10)*2</sup>, which introduces inaccuracies. Moreover C++ does not mandates IEEE 754 conformance. This means that pow(10,2) could be inaccurate on some systems and make a small error down or up, just like in your case.

Solution:

Don't use `pow` at all, or else use `round(pow(10, power))`. In your case, it is better to use regular integer multiplication by 10.