# Gaussian blur algorithm

Tags: c++, image-processing

I'm trying to implement a gaussian blur algorithm, but my weight function is returning the wrong values

```
float gauss(int x, int y, float sigma)
{
    float gauss = 100*exp(-(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)) / (2*pow(sigma,2))) / (pow(sigma, 2)*2*3.14159);
    return gauss;
}
```

I did it based on this tutorial, and according to them i should get this:

[coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyPke.png)

[correct matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfr1C.png)

Comment: What's the wrong value returned by your implementation?

Comment: What values do you pass in for `x` and `y`?

Comment: i passed in (0,1) and got 0.0965324

Comment: This is where i found the tutorial
http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1353768112-Gaussian-Blur-Algorithm

Comment: @OliverHall [Please read this concerning using pow() and integer exponents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os).  The `pow` is a floating point function, thus you're risking getting inaccurate results.  It isn't merely going to multiply the base by itself.

Comment: What's the value of your `sigma`?

Comment: @Oliver Hall: I just ran your function with `sigma` equal to `1.5` and obtained exactly the same results as in that linked tutorial, the only difference being that you for some reason multiply the result by `100`. See for yourself (with that `100` removed): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/100919402619421d . How you managed to obtain `0.0965324` for point `(0, 1)` is not clear to me. How did you inspect your results?

Comment: I was passing in an int for sigma -_- silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using sigma = 1.0, the example you're comparing has used sigma = 1.5?