# Unexpected Value for the Calculation of Catalan's Constant

Tags: c++, boost, equation, floating-accuracy

Here's the function:

```cpp
arbFloat catalan(){
    arbFloat output, n = 0, first, second;
    std::string preComp, postComp;
    do{
        preComp = resizeArbtoString(first);
        first += (1.0 / pow(2.0, 4.0 * n)) * (
                (- 1.0 / (2.0 * pow(8.0*n + 2.0, 2.0))) +
                (1.0 / (4.0 * pow(8.0*n + 3.0, 2.0))) +
                (- 1.0 / (8.0 * pow(8.0*n + 5.0, 2.0))) +
                (1.0 / (8.0 * pow(8.0*n + 6.0, 2.0))) +
                (-1.0 / (16.0 * pow(8.0*n + 7.0, 2.0))) +
                (1.0 / (2.0 * pow(8.0*n + 1.0, 2.0)))
                );
        postComp = resizeArbtoString(first);
        n++;
    } while(preComp != postComp);
    n = 0;
    do{
        preComp = resizeArbtoString(second);
        second += (1.0 / pow(2.0 , 12.0 * n)) * (
                (1.0 / (16.0 * pow(8.0*n + 2, 2.0))) +
                (1.0 / (64.0 * pow(8.0*n + 3, 2.0))) +
                (-1.0 / (512.0 * pow(8.0*n + 5, 2.0))) +
                (-1.0 / (1024.0 * pow(8.0*n + 6, 2.0))) +
                (1.0 / (4096.0 * pow(8.0*n + 7, 2.0))) +
                (1.0 / (8.0 * pow(8.0*n + 1, 2.0)))
                );
        postComp = resizeArbtoString(second);
        n++;
    } while(preComp != postComp);

    output = (3.0*first) - (2.0*second);

    return output;
}
```

This code is meant to calculate the value of [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant). I am using [the method that quickly converges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant#Quickly_converging_series), compared to the slowly-converging equation.

`arbFloat` is a Boost multi-precision [`cpp_dec_float`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/cpp_dec_float.html) with the precision of 100 decimal places:

```
typedef boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<100>> arbFloat
```

The function `resizeArbtoString()` simply converts the variable to a string, and resizes it to account for the first decimal and decimal mark. It isn't important here, and I have verified that it does not impact the result.

I get the value of `first` before and after calculations to stop an infinite loop when the precision is bypassed (same for the variable `second`). The do-while loop checks this. This is what makes it an iterative method.

The two do-while loops separately get the values of the two summations in the equation (image below). Then the `output` variable multiplies the *first* summation by 3, and the second summation by -2, then adds them together.

This function is returning the value of:

```
0.9159456632705320620288006061761625716626752650763000222738355046579667073981960968090933049341304381
```

When the value should instead be:

```
.915965594177219015054603514932384110774149374281672134266498119621763019776254769479356512926115106248574
```

(correct [constant value](https://oeis.org/A006752/constant) via [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A006752))

Here is the equation that I referenced when creating this function:

[image: Equation for quicker convergence towards Catalans Constant]

Why is this returning an imprecise value?

Comment: Do not use [pow with integer exponents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os).  The `pow` function is a floating point function -- there has been several posts where the user is using certain versions of g++ where `pow` will not give exact results when used with integer exponents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `1.0 / 4096.0` term in second should be `-1.0 / 4096.0`.

Comment: @Anonymous -- Read my comments in the main section.  You have potentially other issues concerning the usage of `pow`.