# C++ binary conversion class

Tags: c++

Good Day Guys. So For an Assignment, I was tasked with creating 6 classes of varying functions. I, however, am having trouble with 1 in particular, which requires me to make a class that takes a binary number and convert it into a decimal. Below is what I have from the assignment provided driver file:

```
     #include <iostream>
     using std::cout;
     using std::cin;
     using std::endl;


    #include "binaryconversion.h"

    int main()
    {
    ///*********************************Testing BinaryConversion                     Class************************************************/
    cout<<"Creating BinaryConversion object\n\n\n";
    BinaryConversion binary;
    cout<<"Binary value 111 to decimal = 3\n";//7
    cout<<"Actual function result: " << binary.binaryToDecimal(111);
    cout<<"Binary value 101001 to decimal = 41\n";
    cout<<"Actual function result: " << binary.binaryToDecimal(101001);
    cout<<"Binary value 11100 to decimal = 28\n";
    cout<<"Actual function result: " << binary.binaryToDecimal(11100);

   return 0;
   }
```

For the .h file I have this:

```
   #ifndef BINARYCONVERSION_H
   #define BINARYCONVERSION_H

   #include <iostream>
   using std::cout;
   using std::cin;
   using std::endl;

   class BinaryConversion
   {
   public:
         BinaryConversion();
         void binaryToDecimal(int);


   };

    #endif // BINARYCONVERSION_H
```

And finally, for the .cpp, I have this:

```
    #include "binaryconversion.h"

    BinaryConversion::BinaryConversion()
    {

    }

    void BinaryConversion::binaryToDecimal(int){

        int decimalNumber = 0, y = 0, remainder;
        while (x!=0)
        {
            remainder = n%10;
            n /= 10;
            decimalNumber += remainder*pow(2,y);
            ++y
        }
        return decimalNumber;
    }
```

Now my problem is, that when I build the file, I get errors along the following lines in the driver file:

```
cout<<"Actual function result: " << binary.binaryToDecimal(111);


cout<<"Actual function result: " << binary.binaryToDecimal(101001);


cout<<"Actual function result: " << binary.binaryToDecimal(11100);
```

What could I possibly have done wrong?

edit: current code is as follows after following all of your suggestions of correction :

```
    #include <iostream>
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    using std::endl;

    class BinaryConversion
    {
    public:
        BinaryConversion();
        int binaryToDecimal(int x);

    private:
        int x;
        int n;


    };

    #endif // BINARYCONVERSION_H
```

.cpp:

```
    int BinaryConversion::binaryToDecimal(int x){

       int decimalNumber = 0, y = 0, remainder;
        while (x!=0)
        {
            remainder = x%10;
            x /= 10;
            decimalNumber += remainder* 1 >> y;
            ++y;
        }
        return decimalNumber;
    }
```

Comment: `void` as a return type means you promise not to return any value at all.  Then you go and `return decimalNumber;`, breaking the promise.  One or the other has to change so that they agree.

Comment: so i should remove void and give it something like bool?

Comment: Just a side note, `1 << y` is a much much faster way of computing 2-to-the-power-of-y when `y` is an integer, than calling the `pow` function which works on floating-point numbers.

Comment: Yes, the `void` needs to change.  But figure out what your return type is, don't guess.  (And `bool` is not correct anyway)

Comment: ah I see. so if I figure out what return type it will be, then the program should perform as desired. okay, let me go and try and figure that out and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @AlexisNonya [Do not use pow() with integer exponents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os).  There is no guarantee that `pow()` will return the "correct" answer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie oh okay, well I was fixing up the code based off of suggestions and the pow() says that it wasn't declared in the scope anyways. So if I use Ben Voigt's suggestion of using 1 << y instead, it will be a suitable replacement?

Comment: Try replacing `pow(2,n)` with `1 << n`.  Look up the left shift operator.

Comment: so I replaced the operator, and for the binary value 111, it gave me 3.

Comment: it also only produces only 1 of the 3 test operators needed to be outputted

Comment: You've got more mistakes in your code, so you must not be using the same exact code.

Comment: I managed to get it working. Thanks to all of you who had the patience to help me see how to fix it. TThanks you :D

Comment: @AlexisNonya Is there a reason `binaryToDecimal()` is a method of a class instead of just a free function?

Comment: it was part of an assignment. We had to make six separate classes. This was one of them. It was also the last one. I was supposed to work it with a partner but she got sick and I had to solo it(for the most part since you guys helped me :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **`void BinaryConversion::binaryToDecimal(int)`** function isn't correctly implemented.Firstly, you passed a value to the function but parameter name was't correctly written. It should be `binaryToDecimal(int x)`.For this reason you get this error.

Secondly, The return type shouldn't be void because it return an integer value to the calling function. So return type should be `int` .

Function should be look like the following :

```
void BinaryConversion::binaryToDecimal(int x){
int decimalNumber = 0, y = 0, remainder;
     while (x!=0){
     remainder = x%10;
     x /= 10;
     decimalNumber += remainder*pow(2,y);
     ++y;
   }
   return decimalNumber;
}
```

Comment: SO under the header, the code should read as int binaryToDecimal(int x); and then the function should be as you placed it there ?

Comment: my results came out as Binary value 111 to decimal = 3
Actual function result: 1Binary value 101001 to decimal = 41
Actual function result: 1Binary value 11100 to decimal = 28
Actual function result: 0Press

Comment: You just change the code consists in the function body.

Comment: i think i did something wrong, because i got 4 errors now that i replaced the function with your code.

Comment: What type of error. You should read the error carefully and try to resolve

Comment: after reading over the errors, they are as follows:
no match for 'operator<<'(operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>'and'void')
std::cout<<"Actual Function result: " << binary.binaryToDecimal(111);

no match for 'operator<<'(operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>'and'void')
std::cout<<"Actual Function result: " << binary.binaryToDecimal(101001);

no match for 'operator<<'(operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>'and'void')
std::cout<<"Actual Function result: " << binary.binaryToDecimal(111);

and "forming reference void"

Comment: when you define the class there the function name is also should be `int binaryToDecimal(int x);`

Comment: okay , I managed to get it working. Thanks you so much for all your assistance and patience :D