# Why is this bitset collection algorithm not working?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, binary, bitset

Here's my goal:

1. Create all possible bit strings of length **N**.
2. Once I've created a possible string, I want to take **B** bits at time, covert them to a index, and use that index to fetch a character from the following string:

   ```
   define ALPHABET "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345"
   ```
3. I want to add each character to a string, then print the string once all bits have been parsed.
4. Repeat until all possible bit strings are processed.

Here's my solution:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pow(2, N); i++) {
    // Create bit set.
    std::bitset <N> bits(i);
    // String to hold characters.
    std::string key_val;
    // To hold B bits per time.
    std::bitset <B> temp;
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < bits.size(); j++) {
        // Add to bitset.
        temp[j % B] = bits[j];
        if (j % B == 0) {
            key_val += ALPHABET[temp.to_ulong()];
        }
    }
    std::cout << key_val << std::endl;
    key_val.clear();
}
```

Here's the problem:

The output makes no sense. I can see the program creates really weird sequences, that aren't what I need.

Ideally, the output should be (what I'd like) :

```
aaaaa
aaaab
aaaac
.
.
.
```

And here's the output what I'm getting:

```
aaaaa
baaaa
acaaa
bcaaa
aeaaa
beaaa
agaaa
bgaaa
aiaaa
.
.
.
```

Comment: "not working" is not a useful problem statement.  What results do you get, and what did you expect to get?

Comment: @aschepler I've added more description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "append character" condition triggers immediately (j == 0), this is probably not what you want. You'll also need to take care about the end if bits size is not a multiple of B

```
for (unsigned int j = 0; j < bits.size(); j++) {
    // Add to bitset.
    temp[j % B] = bits[j];
    if (j % B == B - 1 || j == bits.size() - 1) {
        key_val += ALPHABET[temp.to_ulong()];
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Instead of looping over all bits individually, you can probably do something like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < bits.size(); j += B) {
  key_val += ALPHABET[bits.to_ulong() % B];
  bits >>= B;
}
```

**P.S.:** If the bits fit into the loop variable, you don't need a bitset at all.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (1 << N); i++) {
  std::string key_val;
  for (unsigned int j = 0; j < bits.size(); j += B) {
    key_val += ALPHABET[(i >> j) % B];
  }
  std::cout << key_val << std::endl;
}
```

**P.P.S.** You may want / need to count down in the inner loop instead if you want the digits reversed

Comment: I can see how foolish I was being. Appreciate the quick fix!

Comment: One issue with this answer -- you shouldn't use `pow` with integer exponents.  [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os).  There is no guarantee you will get back the correct result when using `pow` this way.