# pow work differently, explain in detail?

Tags: c++

```
int a=pow(100,2);//line 1
int b=ceil(pow(100,2));//line 2
cout<<pow(100,2);//line 3
```

line 1 gives `a=9999` on printing the value of `a`

line 2 gives `b=10000` on printing value of `b`

line 3 prints `10000`

I understood that pow give value `9999.9999` so ceil func. in line 2 gives it the upper value.

But why didn't cout print `9999.9999`

Can anyone explain why pow behave like this return decimal value pow is just a power function why doesn't it simply give `100*100` as answer?

Comment: it doesn't print 9999.9999 because it is an integer not a float....

Comment: and floating point -> integral conversion truncates

Comment: What is bad in this question many people doesn't know that pow return a decimal value

Comment: Please, never use `pow` to compute squares !

Comment: Everyone with an IDE or who had read the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) would know it returns a *floating point* value.

Comment: @shauryauppal I'm pretty sure your compiler gave you a warning such as VS C4244 'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data...

Comment: What is `ceil(100, 2)` supposed to do? `ceil()` only takes 1 argument. Did you mean `ceil(pow(100, 2))`?

Comment: Barmar my question was editted by someone

Comment: @Dadep: no. Line 1 proves that the result of pow is a floating-point value, which is truncated to 9999.

Comment: [Another possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os)

Comment: The OP made the classical mistake of combining two questions in one. One is a duplicate, while the other is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `cout` statement, `pow(100, 2)` is indeed a double-precision value and slightly below `10000` (by a well-known effect of the `pow` function), but the default accuracy setting of `cout` causes rounding and output as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is due to `pow` taking two `double` values as arguments (and returning a `double`) and is typically implemented such that `pow(x, y)` is `exp(y log x)`. This "goes off" for even seemingly trivial input values. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Note that `std::pow` has overloads for integral types which can be helpful when working in integer arithmetic.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the output isn't 9999.9999

Comment: Coupled with the linked question I believe it does.

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Well do please feel free to downvote in that case: it's what the mechanism is for.

Comment: I don't think it would help you understandwhy I am saying that.