# How to initialize a const int array by a function in a header file?

Tags: c++, arrays, macros, initialization, preprocessor

I can easily declare and initialize a constant array member in a header file like so:

```
class MyClass {
 public:
  const int arr[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
}
```

But when the data is defined by a function, I cannot initialize it in the header:

```
#include <cmath>
#define BASE 2
class MyClass {
 public:
  const int arr[4];
  for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
        arr[i] = pow(BASE, i);
  }
}
```

When I try to initialize the array in the class constructor in the .cpp file, I get the obvious `uninitialized member with 'const' type`error, as the array should already be initialized.

How can I initialize a `const int` array in the header file with a preprocessor macro and cmath functions?

Comment: Where's the function?

Comment: @juanchopanza the function in this example is pow.

Comment: If the values are known in advance you could just calculate them, and write just the result in the code. Maybe add some comments to explain the values.

Comment: You can't have a loop in a class definition outside of a function like that.

Comment: @Dialecticus they are not known in advance because they depend on preprocessor variables, as in this example BASE.

Comment: er, `const` is not usually what you want for member variables ...

Comment: Other option is to remove the `const`. That works too.

Comment: Have you considered the fact an plain array is not the correct tool for the job?

Comment: And requiring a function call doesn't mean you need a loop https://ideone.com/WPZ3a1 (BTW, ditch those macros for type-safe `constexpr` variables).

Comment: @StoryTeller You do not realize that this is just an example. In reality the array might have thousands of entries and does need to be initialized in a loop. After all, that's what loops are made for!

Comment: A side note:  watch out for `pow` not always giving you the correct result.

Comment: I don't really care what your use case is if you don't present it. Refer to my first comment. If you still insist on using a plain array despite all advice to the contrary, then write a custom preprocessor in your favorite scripting language to modify the source and generate the initializer. After all, that's what loops are made for!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie What do you mean by "not correct"? The precision is not a problem in my case. A precision of +- 1 is ok as long as the boundaries are correct.

Comment: @uzumaki [This is what I mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os).

Comment: @uzumaki -- This section is for comments, and StoryTeller commented.

Comment: If you are gonna be rude to whomever tries to spare you headaches, you deserve to maintain such code.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to use `BOOST_PP_REPEAT`, if your array can have at most 256 elements (fewer if you're stuck with MSVC). Something like:

```
#define my_elem(z, n, data) pow(BASE, n)

const int data[4] = {BOOST_PP_REPEAT(4, my_elem, "ignored - extra data not needed")};
```

But you should really, *really*, ask yourself why you need a non-`static` but`const` member variable, since that is almost never a useful thing to do, and places major limitations on what your program can do (e.g. it deletes the assignment operator).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (if the array is not too long):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>

constexpr int BASE = 2;

class A {
public:

    A(std::function<int(int)> f);

    const int arr[4];
};

A::A(std::function<int(int)> f) :
    arr{ f(1),f(2), f(3), f(4) }
{
}

int main() {
    auto f = [](int i) { return pow(BASE, i); };
    A a(f);
    for (const auto val : a.arr) {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```