# How to change cout to printf in C++? or how to make the console application run faster?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I got a homework which goes through a compiler which checks if all is correct but it keeps giving result : "time limit exceeded" , the application works as it should in normal C++ compiler but I have to send the code to Themis which doesn't accept it due to "time limit exceeded"

Task : 
Input:
In the first input line is given the integer t (1 ≤ t ≤ 100000) specifying the number of tests. Each test is given by three integers: a, b, m as defined above (1 ≤ a ≤ 10^9, 0 ≤ b ≤ 10^9, 1 ≤ m ≤ 10^6).

Output:

T lines should be printed. In each line, the answer to the query: `(a^b)% m`.

example of input data:

```
2
3 2 10
```

the correct answer is : `9`

One friend told me to change cout to printf which might result in faster runtime but I'm not sure how to do it.

My code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;

    for (int i=0; i<t; ++i)
    {
        int a,b,m;
        long long int x,wynik=1;

        cin>>a>>b>>m;

        x=(long long int) a;

        do
        {
            x%=(long long int)m;
            if (b&1) {
                wynik*=x;
                wynik%=(long long int)m;
            }
            x*=x;
        } while (b>>=1);

        cout <<wynik<<endl;;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *but i keep failling because of too long compiling (over 1 second)* -- What do you mean by "takes 1 second to compile"?  Do you really mean that your program takes more than 1 second to *run*?

Comment: If it's really failing because *compilation* takes too long, you should complain to your instructor.  Your program is very simple and it's not your fault if their test machine is too slow.

Comment: Do you need to perform `a RAISED TO THE POWER OF b`, or `a XOR b`?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but none of the three casts (`(long long int)`) is needed.

Comment: Also, changing your `endl` to `'\n'` will improve run times (note: compilation is NOT the same as running. You're busting run time, not compilation time)

Comment: @John \n would have the same effect with stdout (typically it's line-buffered).

Comment: The error which is shown says : time limit exceeded
in normal c++ compiler the code is correct
but I have to Submit solution in Themis which gives such problems

Comment: @Igor I didn't realize that. My mistake

Comment: I'd recommend using [`std::pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) instead of implementing exponentiation yourself.  (That will also likely give a significant performance boost.)

Comment: @Roksana I think it's just a bad error message. There's no way this code takes over a second to compile unless the hardware is bad. Using printf over cout is not going to meaningfully speed up compilation times.

Comment: @Roksana *time limit exceeded* - -Which means that your code takes too long.  And to be honest, playing around with `cout` statements as opposed to `printf` does little, if anything, in increasing your knowledge of C++.  If you can't drive a car, picking a blue car instead of a red car isn't going to teach you how to drive a car.

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistyping with "too long compiling" instead of "runs too much time"
I got C++ this semester so I'm also quite new to it.

Comment: you can still edit your title and question here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60515807/edit

Comment: Are you sure your input and expected output is correct? `2 3 2 10` will hang, because the first `2` means that the application wants 2 sets of a/b/m, but there is only one. When I run your application with `1 3 2 10` it runs in 4ms. I'm guessing your application is taking too long because it is waiting for the second set of a/b/m

Comment: @0x5453  Reminder: `std::pow` is a floating point function and there may be some accuracy issues when converting to integers.

Comment: Is it possible one of the test cases is introducing an overflow situation, thus breaking the normal loop?

Comment: @0x5453 Wrong, the `pow` function doesn't really calculate "`a` to the power of `b` **modulo `c`**". For almost any value `b`, catastrophic loss of precision is guaranteed. And even for small powers, one has to take care rounding the result to the nearest integer instead of zero.

Comment: Swapping output mechanisms won't help. You're getting that message because you designed a suboptimal algorithm and it's failing the hard testcases. Design a better algorithm. Think about its _algorithmic complexity_; reduce that. Think about _how it scales_; improve that. That is, ultimately, the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings the complexity of this code doesn't seem bad at all. It's O(t log(b)), which seems about as good as you could hope for.

Comment: @0x5453 [See this about using pow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os/25678721#25678721).  In short, the OP **should** be implementing `pow` by hand and **not** use `std::pow`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Seems like that could be easily fixed with `std::round(std::pow(...))`, no?  (As long as the exponents are small enough that the accumulated error is < 0.5, which may not be the case for OP's example.)

Answer (score 1):

Answering the literal question, how to change `cout` to `printf`.

---

Instead of `#include <iostream>`, you want `#include <cstdio>`, which is short for "C language standard input and output".

Instead of `cout <<wynik<<endl;`, you want `printf("%d\n", (int) wynik)`. Here, `"%d\n"` is a formatting string saying "print the next argument, which should be `int`, in decimal, and then print a newline".

You may also want to use C-style input, then change `cin>>a>>b>>m;` into `scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &m);`. This says "read three decimal integers, one into variable `a` (`&` is taking an address of a variable), the other into `b`, and yet another into `m`.

---

That said, note that relative speed of C-style and C++-style input and output depends on plenty of factors, including compiler version, OS, and environment. In another testing environment, you may find `cout` is actually on par with, or faster than, `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use cin and cout you can insert this lines in main()

```
cin.tie(0);
cout.tie(0);
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
```

and it should work as fast as priantf and scanf.