# Why does Kattis return this as invalid?

Tags: c++

https://open.kattis.com/problems/pot

> **Pot**
>
> The teacher has sent an e-mail to her students with the following task: “Write a program that will determine and output the value of *X* if given the statement:
>
> *X* = *number*<sub>*1*</sub><sup>*pow*<sub>*1*</sub></sup> + *number*<sub>*2*</sub><sup>*pow*<sub>*2*</sub></sup> + … + *number*<sub>*N*</sub><sup>*pow*<sub>*N*</sub></sup>
>
> and it holds that *number*<sub>*1*</sub>, *number*<sub>*2*</sub> to *number*<sub>*N*</sub> are integers, and *pow*<sub>*1*</sub>, *pow*<sub>*2*</sub> to *pow*<sub>*N*</sub> are one-digit integers.” Unfortunately, when the teacher downloaded the task to her computer, the text formatting was lost so the task transformed into a sum of *N* integers:
>
> X = P1 + P2 + … + PN
>
> For example, without text formatting, the original task in the form of *X* *=* *21*<sup>*2*</sup> + *125*<sup>*3*</sup> became a task in the form of *X* *=* *212* *+* *1253*. Help the teacher by writing a program that will, for given *N* integers from *P*<sub>*1*</sub> to *P*<sub>*N*</sub> determine and output the value of *X* from the original task.
>
> Input:
>
> The first line of input contains the integer *N* (1 ≤ *N* ≤ 10), the number of the addends from the task. Each of the following *N* lines contains the integer *P*<sub>*i*</sub> (10 ≤ *P*<sub>*i*</sub> ≤ 9999, *i* = 1 … *N*) from the task.
>
> Output:
>
> The first and only line of output must contain the value of *X* (*X* ≤ 1000000000) from the original task.

---

I recently just started coding in C++ and was told Kattis was a good website to start practicing on. I have started to freshen up on the basics for my upcoming CS 2 class in the fall and I am confused why my answer is not getting accepted. Any answers would be greatly appreciated!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nums, number, total, temp;
    cin >> nums;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
        cin >> number;
        temp = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        total = total + pow(number, temp);
    }

    cout << total;
}
```

Comment: Initialize `total`.

Comment: Declare variables as close to where they're needed as possible.

Comment: Use `/=` and `+=` for better readability.

Comment: Thank you! Setting total = 0 gave an accepted answer.

Comment: @Booboo The problem with your solution is that it could lead to [erroneous results if pow() is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os).  The bottom line is to not use `pow` to compute powers using integer exponents, unless the final result is too large to be represented as an integer.