# why does the pow function seem to be glitching?

Tags: c++, pow

For the below code:

```
int digsum(ll num) {  //function to calculate sum of digits
    if (num < 0)
        num = abs(num);
    int ans = 0;
    while (num != 0) {
        ans = ans + num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return ans;
}

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0);

    int a, b, c, cnt = 0;
    long long x;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 72; i++) {
        x = (b * (pow(i, a))) + c;
        if (i == digsum(x) && x < mod) {
            cout << x << " ";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the case `a,b,c = 3,2,8` respectively and `i=19;`
`pow(19,3)` is supposed to calculate 19^3 but when I replace `pow` by (19x19x19), this specific case is getting satisfied, where as that wasn't the case with the `pow` function.
Can someone explain what the problem is?

Comment: What type is `ll` ?  And what is the value for `mod` ?

Comment: Also, what value did you expect to have computed ?  And what you actually getting?

Comment: ll is long long and mod is 10^9 -1@selbie

Comment: When I run your program and enter `3 2 8`, it spits out `10 2008 13726`.  What values did you expect it to print?

Comment: but im not getting 13726 in the output, for some reason it is calculating x as 13725 for that case

Comment: Can you add all your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My psychic powers suggest that your standard library's implementation of `pow` is not precise.  I recall a discussion on SO a while back on this topic.  Remember, `pow` returns a floating point value.  I can't repro it, but it's entirely possibly your invocation of `pow(19,3)` returns `6858.999999999` or similar due to the way it's optimized.

Indeed, this [this page](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/5-3-modulus-and-exponentiation) says as much:

> Due to rounding errors in floating point numbers, the results of pow() may not be precise (even if you pass it integers or whole numbers).

Also, this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os) suggests the same thing.

I wouldn't have suspected it, but there you go.

Consider doing this as a workaround:

```
long long power = nearbyint(pow(i,a));
x = b * power + c;
```

Comment: but if pow returned a float and rounding off was the problem, printing `d` where `float d = pow(19, 3);` should display a floating point value, but that isn't the case; it justs displays 6859

Comment: Because print functions round too.

Comment: what if I print using `cout<<(float)d;`

Comment: That's won't do anything different. But this will: `cout << std::setprecision(32) << modified;`