# Problem with Reversing Large Integers On Leetcode?

Tags: c++, integer, overflow

I was working on this problem from Leetcode where it has this requirement of reversing numbers whilst staying within the +/-2^31 range. I checked out other solutions made for this problem, and from there created my own solution to it. It worked successfully for numbers ranging from 10 to less than 99,999,999. Going more than that(when trying to submit the code to move to the next question) would throw an error saying:

**"Line 17: Char 23: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 445600005 * 10 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp)"**

This was the input given when trying to submit the code: 1534236469

My code

```
class Solution {
public:
    int reverse(int x) {
      int flag = 0;
      int rev = 0;
      if (x >= pow(2, 31)) {
          return 0;
      } else {
        if (x < 0) {
            flag = 1;
            x = abs(x);
        }
        while(x > 0) {
            rev = rev * 10 + x % 10;
            x /= 10;
        }
        if (flag == 1) {
            rev = rev*(-1);
        }
        
    return rev;    
    }  
    }
};
```

As you can see from my code, I added an if statement that would basically **return 0** if the number was greater than 2^31. Unfortunately, this was wrong.

Can anyone explain how this can be fixed? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Reversing integers is very easy if you hold them as a string (decimal).

Comment: Reversing 1534236469 gets you outside that range.  You should check your result, not the input. (And the limit is the integer `1 << 31`, not the floating-point number `pow(2,31)`.)

Comment: I don't get it I've learned everywhere that using pow raises the power of the number to what you want??

Comment: @Thanos because they all convert to floating-point https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow And now you are in that wonderful place were you have to workout if a particular floating point representation can hold the integer value exactly. Best to avoid even asking that question.

Comment: @Thanos *I've learned everywhere that using pow raises the power of the number to what you want* -- [Well, this will surprise you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os).  Binary floating point is not schoolbook, base 10 arithmetic.  The bottom line is to not use floating point arithmetic or functions for integer-based problems.  That's another thing "Leetcode" and other such sites seem to leave out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem statement asks to return 0 if **reversed number does not belong to integer range** :

> If reversing `x` causes the value to go outside the signed 32-bit integer range `[-2^31, 2^31 - 1]`, then `return 0`.

In your code you checked if input fits in integer range but their arises a corner case when the integer has 10 digits and last digit is >2 (and for some cases 2).

Lets consider the input `1534236469`: 1534236469 < 2^31 - 1

**so program executes as expected now lets trace last few steps of program execution :** `rev = 964632435` and `x = 1` problem arises when following statement is executed :

```cpp
rev = rev * 10 + x % 10;
```

Now, even though input can be represented as integer `rev * 10`  i.e. `9646324350`  is greater than integer range and correct value that should be returned is **zero**

### Fix ?

#### 1. Lets consider 10 digit case independently

Even though this can be done, it gives rise to unnecessary complications when last digit is **2**

#### 2. Make `rev` a `long integer`

This works perfectly and is also accepted, but sadly this is not expected when solving this problem as statement explicitly asks to not use 64-bit integers

> **Assume the environment does not allow you to store 64-bit integers (signed or unsigned).**

#### 3. Checking before multyplying by 10 ?

This works as expected. Before multyplying `rev` by `10` check if it is `>= (pow(2,31)/10)`

```cpp
while(x > 0) {
            if (rev >= pow(2, 31)/10 )
                return 0;
            rev = rev * 10 + x % 10;  
            x /= 10;
        }
```

I hope this solves your doubt !! Comment if you find something wrong as this is my first answer.

***Note* : The following `if` statement is unnecessary as input is always a 32-bit integer**

> Given a signed **32-bit integer `x`**

```cpp
if (x >= pow(2, 31)) {
          return 0;
      }
```

**Edit** : As most of the comments pointed it out, instead of `pow(2,31)`, use `INT_MAX` macro as it suffices here.

Comment: Thank you for the response it really helped me understand this in a better. However, with the whole INT_MAX thing, how would you use it instead of the pow?

Comment: [Numeric Limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) page describes use of these limits. You can refer this or instead a quick google search will lead to more readable posts.

Comment: Alright will do, thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static int reverse(int x) {
        boolean isNegative = false;
        if (x < 0) {
            isNegative = true;
            x = -x;
        }
        long reverse = 0;
        while (x > 0) {
            reverse = reverse * 10 + x % 10;
            x=x/10;
        }
        if (reverse > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (int) (isNegative ? -reverse : reverse);
    }
```

Comment: This question is tagged C++ but that's not C++