# The given code fails for larger values even after changing variable from int to double to long

Tags: c++, loops, binary, masking

This was the problem statement.

*Complement of Base 10 Integer

The complement of an integer is the integer you get when you flip all the 0's to 1's and all the 1's to 0's in its binary representation.

For example, The integer 5 is "101" in binary and its complement is "010" which is the integer 2.
Given an integer n, return its complemet*

I saw some solutions to this proble using bit masking, which is something I **will** get to, but first I want to know why this code given below does not work?

It works for smaller values, but for
input: 299475
output: 224816
Expected Output: 224812

And the problem seems to persist for greater values.

```
#include <math.h>
class Solution {
#include <math.h> 
public:
int bitwiseComplement(int n) {
long a = 0;
int i = 0;
if ( n == 0) { 
     return 1;
}
while ( n != 0 ) { 
    int b = n & 1;
    if ( b == 1) { 
        b = 0;
    }
    else if (b == 0){ 
        b = 1;
    }
    n = n >> 1;
    a = a + (b * pow(10, i));
    i++;
        
}
long sol = 0;
int k = 0;
while ( a != 0) { 
    int b = a % 10;
    sol = sol + (b * pow(2, k));
    k++;
    a = a/10;
}
return sol;}
};
```

Comment: Do not use `pow` for integer-based problems.  The `pow` is a floating point function, and with that, you will inherit all the issues associated with floating point calculations (such as [inexact results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os)).

Comment: Just as a side note: `~number` already gives you the binary complement in one single operation... And *'base 10'* is misleading if you want to calculate binary complements, as there's a base10 complement as well: 647 gets 352 – and their bit patterns are not complements in binary…

Comment: Wait a second – you are trying to calculate a number that, in base 10, has the same digits as the original number in binary? That number will get *much* larger than the original one if that one is large, too, most likely won't fit into `int`, thus you suffer from overflow (undefined behaviour for signed integers!). `long` on many systems (e.g. windows – in contrast to e.g. 64-bit linux) has the same size as `int` so wouldn't help out either, instead try `long long` (or don't rely on system's sizes at all and try `uint64_t` from `cstdint` header.

Comment: Be aware, too, that, in general, if you are operating on bit patterns only then *unsigned* types are better choice, not suffering from left-shifting values into negative (UB actually, too) if values get too large.

Comment: Why do you calculate the result as a base 10 binary number? Why not just calculate the result directly? (`a = a + b << i`)

Comment: About too large numbers: 9 is the largest power of 10 that yet fits into a 32 bit (signed) integer – accordingly 2^10 - 1 = 1023 is the largest number that you still can calculate its representation in base 10 without losing information (actually provoking UB) – and actually the same problem persists even with *unsigned* 32 bit integer (10^10 doesn't fit into either), just that you avoid the UB...

Comment: 299475  is 1001001000111010011 in binary. 1001001000111010011 interpreted as a *decimal* number is a much larger number and requires 60 binary digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you are calculating a number of which the decimal representation looks like the binary representation of the original number.

The problem with is that these numbers are *much* larger than the original ones (e.g. 8 gets 1000, 16 10000, ...).

10<sup>10</sup> already won't fit into 32 bits any more (assuming `int` – signed or unsigned – having that size on your system) – so largest number you can safely convert this way without losing information is 2<sup>10</sup> - 1 = 1023, any number larger will provoke overflow – and even worse: as you opted for *signed* integers actually *undefined behaviour*.

Now `long` on many systems (e.g. 32-bit linux or windows – in contrast to e.g. 64-bit linux) has the same size as `int`, so it doesn't help out either in that case; you might possibly try `unsigned long long` instead or, for not having to rely on OS-specific sizes, `uint64_t` from `<cstdint>` header. The largest power of 10 that still fits into then is 19, so the largest number you still can calculate its representation of is now 2<sup>20</sup> - 1 = 1 048 575. But that's still pretty small…

Now `double`, in contrast, has even worse precision than an equally sized signed integer as it uses one bit for the sign and 11 bits for an exponent, remaining 52 bits for the mantissa, so 53 bits for the value, including the implicit one, thus allowing to represent 10<sup>15</sup> precisely, thus 2<sup>16</sup> - 1 = 65535 is the maximum value you can calculate the representation of.

Solution to this problem is skipping the intermediate representation in base-10 and calculate the base 2 complement directly:

```
unsigned int bit = 0;
while(n) // uint32_t!
{
   c |= !(n & 1) << bit++; // or 1 - (n & 1), if you prefer...
   n >>= 1;
}
```