# What if we Initializing variable with 'double' instead of 'integer' while using pow() function as equation in c++?

Tags: c++, pow, cmath

I have been trying to solve a basic Armstrong problem in C++ using the `pow()` function.

I'm encountering unexpected behavior while implementing a solution to compute Armstrong numbers in C++ using the pow() function. An Armstrong number is defined as a number that is equal to the sum of its digits raised to the power of the number of digits. While my code successfully identifies Armstrong numbers in most cases, it fails to do so for certain inputs, notably when the number 153 is entered.

### Specific Issues Encountered:

- **Unexpected Output:** When inputting the number 153, the program produces unexpected results during the calculation process.
- **Incorrect Sum:** The calculated sum of digits raised to the power of the number of digits does not match the expected result for the number 153.
- **Observations:** Upon debugging and researching, I've observed discrepancies in the output generated by the **`pow()`** function, particularly when used with integral arguments.

### Proposed Solutions Investigated:

1. **Truncation Issue:** I explored the possibility of truncation errors occurring due to the conversion of **`double`** results to **`int`**.
2. **Alternative Implementations:** I considered alternative computation methods, such as using **`std::pow`** from **`<cmath>`** or manually calculating powers to mitigate potential issues with **`pow()`**.

While calculating the `pow()` function, I encountered a problem the function gives unexpected output while solving a specific number -> '153' as: (But giving correct result while solving other Armstrong numbers like 4, 9, 370, 371, etc)

---

> `Enter a number: 153`
>
> `Sum: 27`
>
> `Sum: 151`
>
> `Sum: 152`
>
> `153 is not an armstrong number.`

**CODE: -**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num, temp, digit, sum = 0;

    cout << "\nEnter a number: ";
    cin >> num;
    temp = num;
    digit = log10(num) + 1;

    while (temp > 0)
    {
        sum += pow((temp % 10), (digit));
        temp /= 10;
        cout << "\nSum: " << sum;
    }

    if (sum == num) {
        cout << endl << num << " is an armstrong number.";
    } else {
        cout << endl << num << " is not an armstrong number.";
    }

    cout << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

---

There is a solution I found on stack overflow:

Although it's fashionable to expect `pow` to return the best possible result, particularly with integral arguments1, neither the C++ standard nor the IEEE754 floating point standard insists on that.

And with a truncation of the `double` result to an `int`, your result could be 1 less than expected.

The solution is to write out small powers in longhand: `temp * temp * temp` in your case.

You *might* get a better result with `std::pow` from `<cmath>` as then your compiler will pick an overload more suitable for your calculation. – @[Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2380830/bathsheba)

Also,

If you put a `cout << pow(temp,3)` just after `sum = sum + pow(temp,3)` you will see expected result i.e 27, 125 and 1 on passing 153 and 153 as argument. But if you put `cout << sum` just after `sum = sum + pow(temp,3)` then unexpected result are shown i.e. 27, 151 and 152 . Instead of 151 there must be 152. – @[Jayant Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10475339/jayant-sharma)

---

But after trial and error, there is a solution I came up with.

If we initialize the variable with `double` where we storing the `pow()` function equation will result the correct output.

Like in above code if we initialize `double sum = 0;`, the output will be expected as:

> `Enter a number: 153`
>
> `Sum: 27`
>
> `Sum: 152`
>
> `Sum: 153`
>
> `153 is an armstrong number.`

**CODE: -**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num, temp, digit;
    double sum = 0;

    cout << "\nEnter a number: ";
    cin >> num;
    temp = num;
    digit = log10(num) + 1;

    while (temp > 0)
    {
        sum += pow((temp % 10), (digit));
        temp /= 10;
        cout << "\nSum: " << sum << endl;
    }

    if (sum == num) {
        cout << endl << num << " is an armstrong number.";
    } else {
        cout << endl << num << " is not an armstrong number.";
    }

    cout << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

#### Resolution Attempted:

After experimentation, I found that initializing the **`sum`** variable as a **`double`** instead of an **`int`** yielded the expected output for Armstrong numbers, including 153.

#### Request for Assistance:

I seek insights into the root cause of the unexpected behavior and recommendations for optimizing the computation of Armstrong numbers using the **`pow()`** function in C++.

Comment: Just don't use floating-point functions for integer operations. A function like `pow` is quite easy to implement for integers. And for your case it might even be possible to do it without the use of both `pow` or `log10`.

Comment: The simple answer is don't use the `pow` function for integer arithmetic, but it seems you don't want that answer. If you must use the `pow` function then use it in conjunction with the `round` function so that you get the correct integral result. `round(pow(temp % 10, digit))`

Comment: It's a bad idea to change `int` to `double`, that doesn't make sense because your values are integers so declare them as such. Plus the values returned by `pow` don't change just because your variables are a different type. It might solve the problem but only by luck because one error cancels out another.

Comment: `sum += pow((temp % 10), (digit))` -- TL;DR.  Your program is potentially broken.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os).

Comment: `std::pow` is using floating pointer numbers, theres nothing you can do about that. If you need integers simply do not use `std::pow`

Comment: Your "Armstrong" problem is integer-based.  Usage of any floating point functions or floating point calculations basically invalidates the program.  Yes, you may come up with the right answers using `pow`, `log10` etc., but the program is still fundamentally flawed.  It's like using the wrong sized nuts and bolts to build a table, but the wrong sized nuts and bolts just happen to "work" (hopefully) -- but that still means that the table is built using wrong components..

Comment: the insights you are looking for are summarized here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: "...and recommendations for optimizing the computation of Armstrong ..." *optimization* is the wrong word as long as you are getting wrong results. Beginners often push for optimization and forget that correctness is so much more important. You can get a wrong result in 0 time, but it is useless

Comment: Watch this : [Floating Point Numbers - Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0)