# Round() in-built function does not work for Turbo C++ v4.0

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

This round() is not under math.h header. How to make it work?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main()
{
float i=5.4;
printf("%f\t%f",i,round(i));
getch();
}
```

Comment: Turbo C++ is off any c++ standards.

Comment: Ver 4.0 is from 1994. You better use something from this millennium.

Comment: I agree with @BoPersson, but you can try searching the headers for `round` function

Comment: Maybe write your own round() function if your compiler doesn't have it?  Have it add 0.5, convert to int, then return as float?

Comment: If you need an implementation see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572556/concise-way-to-implement-round-in-c

Comment: `<math.h>` and `<stdio.h>` are deprecated in every C++ standard. Get some up-to-date learning material.

Comment: Suggest best compiler for C and C++

Answer (score 2):

It's not available. You need to write you own using `floor` and `ceil`.

But better yet, get an up-to-date compiler. There's no excuse to be still using Turbo C++, and the language and libraries have changed incredibly since 1993.

Comment: Yes, it is true, but keep in mind many students are still pushed to use Turbo C++ for learning at University !!!

Comment: Then they should switch universities. After all, if the purpose of the university is to teach young skulls full of mush the necessary skills for them to find gainful employment, any university like this one would be a major fail.

Comment: Agree with Sam; I wouldn't hire a candidate who wrote code like that like that during the interview. So your university is teaching you things that will actively cause you to NOT be hired.

Comment: Which compiler is best to use? @Roddy

Comment: @DeeprajBhujel "Best" is impossible to say, but if I was learning I'd want a free, commonly-used  and modern compiler that could run on many platforms. Like *gcc* for instance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
clrscr();
float f=5.4;
int rounded,k;
k=f//Initialising the value of k as the integral value of f
if((f-k)>=0.5)
{
 rounded = k+1;
}
else
{
 rounded = k;
}
printf("The rounded value is %d",rounded);
getch();
}
```

Comment: I think this code runs fine in Turbo-C++ and will give you your desired answer.

Comment: Also, Turbo-C++ may be old but it is very effective and using various logics, you can mostly do all what you need.

Comment: No its not. The code you wrote is not paradigmatic C++ and will be difficult to maintain in the future. For example conio.h isn't found on modern systems. There is a reasonable chance that your rounding function doesn't have the correct behavior for all floating point values (such as nans).