# How to round to the closest whole number without using known functions in c?

Tags: c

like 52.7-->53, 5.5-->6, 3.2->3

Comment: Write your own.....

Comment: @AliVolkanATLI *without using known functions*.

Comment: Similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572556/concise-way-to-implement-round-in-c

Comment: By the time you post it here, it will be known.

Comment: Which way do you want to round negative numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle negative numbers properly (`-52.7 ==> -53 (away from zero)`), you must check if the initial value is negative:

```
((int)(num + ((num > 0)? +0.5 : -0.5)))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int round(float num) {
  return (int)(num + 0.5);
}
```

Edit: This will not work for large value of float and negative numbers.

**Edit Again:** This was the simple idea of how rounding works, but after reading comment on question this thread : [Concise way to implement round() in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4572556/468724)
has everything explained for a proper implementation of `round()` function

Comment: Note that this rounding mode is *round upwards*, not *round away from zero*, which might not be what someone expects.  Also, it won't work for large values which `int` cannot represent.

Comment: You need to check double to int conversion, since possible loss of data