# Generate next largest or smallest representable floating point number without bit twiddling

Tags: c++, floating-point

Given an arbitrary finite floating point number, is there a way to determine what the next representable floating point number? For example, given 1.0f, by definition the next largest representable number is 1.0f + std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon(). Is there a way to synthesize an epsilon for any value - not just 1.0f - without resorting to bit twiddling and/or explicit knowledge of how the machine represents floating point values?

Comment: I don't think it can be done without bit twiddling and explicit knowledge of the machine representation, but I'm not super-familiar with std::numeric_limits<float> stuff

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In C++11, you use `std::nextafter()`.  Lacking that, on a C99 system, you use `nextafterf`,  `nextafter`, or `nextafterl` from the C math library (for types `float`, `double`, and `long double`, respectively).

Comment: There's also the `nextafter()` type-generic macro in `<tgmath.h>` (that's in C99; I don't know whether C++ has it).

Comment: Ha! I had no idea this existed.

Comment: In Visual C++ 2010 it appears to be `_nextafter`.

Answer (score 3):

```
int exponent;
significand= frexp(number, &exponent);
significand+= epsilon;
next= ldexp(significand, exponent);
```

What this does is extract the mantissa, increment it by the floating point epsilon, then rebuild the floating point number. That should be the next representable number you would get by fiddling with the bits of the mantissa (and exponent on mantissa overflow).

Comment: I upvoted, because it is useful to me, but I don't think this is valid for the entire range. In testing my implementation I tried moving away from zero and then back to it, but I couldn't get to zero.

Comment: I don't believe this handles denormalized values correctly, or if the significand overflows, in which case the exponent needs to be incremented.