# How do I convert std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon() in c?

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to use `std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()` in c.

The description says

> Returns the machine epsilon, that is, the difference between 1.0 and
>   the next value representable by the floating-point type T.

How can I represent the identical value in c?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883900/epsilon-for-various-float-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#include <float.h>`

and use

`FLT_EPSILON` 
`DBL_EPSILON`
`LDBL_EPSILON`

See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/

Comment: My apologies, I was going off of Zack's quoted text, which is "the largest finite value that can be represented by the type", but that's not actually what `std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()` is. `FLT_EPSILON` matches that, it just doesn't match the quoted text.

Comment: @KevinBallard I'm sorry it was my mistake. I just edited my post.