# SSE vector wrapper type performance compared to bare __m128

Tags: c++, assembly, optimization, x86, sse

I found an interesting [Gamasutra article](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/132636/designing_fast_crossplatform_simd_.php) about SIMD pitfalls, which states that it is not possible to reach the performance of the "pure" `__m128` type with wrapper types. Well I was skeptical, so I downloaded the project files and fabricated a comparable test case.

It turned out (for my surprise) that the wrapper version is significantly slower. Since I don't want to talk about just the thin air, the test cases are the following:

**In the 1st case** `Vec4` is a simple alias of the `__m128` type with some operators:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>

using Vec4 = __m128;

inline __m128 VLoad(float f)
{
    return _mm_set_ps(f, f, f, f);
};

inline Vec4& operator+=(Vec4 &va, Vec4 vb)
{
    return (va = _mm_add_ps(va, vb));
};

inline Vec4& operator*=(Vec4 &va, Vec4 vb)
{
    return (va = _mm_mul_ps(va, vb));
};

inline Vec4 operator+(Vec4 va, Vec4 vb)
{
    return _mm_add_ps(va, vb);
};

inline Vec4 operator-(Vec4 va, Vec4 vb)
{
    return _mm_sub_ps(va, vb);
};

inline Vec4 operator*(Vec4 va, Vec4 vb)
{
    return _mm_mul_ps(va, vb);
};
```

**In the 2nd case** `Vec4` is a lightweight wrapper around `__m128`.
It is not a complete wrapper, just a short sketch which covers the issue. The operators wrap exactly the same intrinsics, the only difference is (since 16-byte alignment cannot be applied on arguments) that they take `Vec4` as `const` reference:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>

struct Vec4
{
    __m128 simd;

    inline Vec4() = default;
    inline Vec4(const Vec4&) = default;
    inline Vec4& operator=(const Vec4&) = default;

    inline Vec4(__m128 s)
        : simd(s)
    {}

    inline operator __m128() const
    {
        return simd;
    }

    inline operator __m128&()
    {
        return simd;
    }
};

inline __m128 VLoad(float f)
{
    return _mm_set_ps(f, f, f, f);
};

inline Vec4 VAdd(const Vec4 &va, const Vec4 &vb)
{
    return _mm_add_ps(va, vb);
    // return _mm_add_ps(va.simd, vb.simd); // doesn't make difference
};

inline Vec4 VSub(const Vec4 &va, const Vec4 &vb)
{
    return _mm_sub_ps(va, vb);
    // return _mm_sub_ps(va.simd, vb.simd); // doesn't make difference
};

inline Vec4 VMul(const Vec4 &va, const Vec4 &vb)
{
    return _mm_mul_ps(va, vb);
    // return _mm_mul_ps(va.simd, vb.simd); // doesn't make difference
};
```

**And here is the test kernel** which produces different performance with  different versions of `Vec4`:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>

struct EQSTATE
{
    // Filter #1 (Low band)

    Vec4  lf;       // Frequency
    Vec4  f1p0;     // Poles ...
    Vec4  f1p1;     
    Vec4  f1p2;
    Vec4  f1p3;

    // Filter #2 (High band)

    Vec4  hf;       // Frequency
    Vec4  f2p0;     // Poles ...
    Vec4  f2p1;
    Vec4  f2p2;
    Vec4  f2p3;

    // Sample history buffer

    Vec4  sdm1;     // Sample data minus 1
    Vec4  sdm2;     //                   2
    Vec4  sdm3;     //                   3

    // Gain Controls

    Vec4  lg;       // low  gain
    Vec4  mg;       // mid  gain
    Vec4  hg;       // high gain

};  

static float vsaf = (1.0f / 4294967295.0f);   // Very small amount (Denormal Fix)
static Vec4 vsa = VLoad(vsaf);

Vec4 TestEQ(EQSTATE* es, Vec4& sample)
{
    // Locals

    Vec4  l,m,h;      // Low / Mid / High - Sample Values

    // Filter #1 (lowpass)

    es->f1p0  += (es->lf * (sample   - es->f1p0)) + vsa;
    //es->f1p0 = VAdd(es->f1p0, VAdd(VMul(es->lf, VSub(sample, es->f1p0)), vsa));

    es->f1p1  += (es->lf * (es->f1p0 - es->f1p1));
    //es->f1p1 = VAdd(es->f1p1, VMul(es->lf, VSub(es->f1p0, es->f1p1)));

    es->f1p2  += (es->lf * (es->f1p1 - es->f1p2));
    //es->f1p2 = VAdd(es->f1p2, VMul(es->lf, VSub(es->f1p1, es->f1p2)));

    es->f1p3  += (es->lf * (es->f1p2 - es->f1p3));
    //es->f1p3 = VAdd(es->f1p3, VMul(es->lf, VSub(es->f1p2, es->f1p3)));

    l          = es->f1p3;

    // Filter #2 (highpass)

    es->f2p0  += (es->hf * (sample   - es->f2p0)) + vsa;
    //es->f2p0 = VAdd(es->f2p0, VAdd(VMul(es->hf, VSub(sample, es->f2p0)), vsa));

    es->f2p1  += (es->hf * (es->f2p0 - es->f2p1));
    //es->f2p1 = VAdd(es->f2p1, VMul(es->hf, VSub(es->f2p0, es->f2p1)));

    es->f2p2  += (es->hf * (es->f2p1 - es->f2p2));
    //es->f2p2 = VAdd(es->f2p2, VMul(es->hf, VSub(es->f2p1, es->f2p2)));

    es->f2p3  += (es->hf * (es->f2p2 - es->f2p3));
    //es->f2p3 = VAdd(es->f2p3, VMul(es->hf, VSub(es->f2p2, es->f2p3)));

    h          = es->sdm3 - es->f2p3;
    //h = VSub(es->sdm3, es->f2p3);

    // Calculate midrange (signal - (low + high))

    m          = es->sdm3 - (h + l);
    //m = VSub(es->sdm3, VAdd(h, l));

    // Scale, Combine and store

    l         *= es->lg;
    m         *= es->mg;
    h         *= es->hg;

    //l = VMul(l, es->lg);
    //m = VMul(m, es->mg);
    //h = VMul(h, es->hg);

    // Shuffle history buffer 

    es->sdm3   = es->sdm2;
    es->sdm2   = es->sdm1;
    es->sdm1   = sample;                

    // Return result

    return(l + m + h);
    //return(VAdd(l, VAdd(m, h)));
}

//make these as globals to enforce the function call;
static Vec4 sample[1024], result[1024];
static EQSTATE es;

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int ii=0; ii<1024; ii++)
    {
        result[ii] = TestEQ(&es, sample[ii]);
    }

    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t1 - t0).count();
    std::cout << "timing: " << t << '\n';

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Link to working code**

- https://godbolt.org/g/fZ8X0N

---

MSVC 2015 generated assembly for the **1st version**:

```
;   COMDAT ?TestEQ@@YA?AT__m128@@PAUEQSTATE@@AAT1@@Z
_TEXT   SEGMENT
?TestEQ@@YA?AT__m128@@PAUEQSTATE@@AAT1@@Z PROC      ; TestEQ, COMDAT
; _es$dead$ = ecx
; _sample$ = edx
    vmovaps xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [edx]
    vsubps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+16
    vmovaps xmm2, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?vsa@@3T__m128@@A
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+16
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+16, xmm0
    vsubps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+32
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+32
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+32, xmm0
    vsubps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+48
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+48
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+48, xmm0
    vsubps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+64
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
    vaddps  xmm4, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+64
    vmovaps xmm2, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+80
    vmovaps xmm1, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+192
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+64, xmm4
    vmovaps xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [edx]
    vsubps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+96
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?vsa@@3T__m128@@A
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+96
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+96, xmm0
    vsubps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+112
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+112
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+112, xmm0
    vsubps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+128
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+128
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+128, xmm0
    vsubps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+144
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+144
    vsubps  xmm2, xmm1, xmm0
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+144, xmm0
    vmovaps xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+176
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+192, xmm0
    vmovaps xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+160
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+176, xmm0
    vmovaps xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [edx]
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+160, xmm0
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm4, xmm2
    vsubps  xmm0, xmm1, xmm0
    vmulps  xmm1, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+224
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm2, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+240
    vaddps  xmm1, xmm1, xmm0
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm4, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+208
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm1, xmm0
    ret 0
?TestEQ@@YA?AT__m128@@PAUEQSTATE@@AAT1@@Z ENDP      ; TestEQ
```

MSVC 2015 generated assembly for the **2nd version**:

```
?TestEQ@@YA?AUVec4@VMATH@@PAUEQSTATE@@AAU12@@Z PROC ; TestEQ, COMDAT
; ___$ReturnUdt$ = ecx
; _es$dead$ = edx
    push    ebx
    mov ebx, esp
    sub esp, 8
    and esp, -8                 ; fffffff8H
    add esp, 4
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, DWORD PTR [ebx+4]
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _sample$[ebx]
    vmovaps xmm2, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A
    vmovaps xmm1, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+192
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+4], ebp
    vmovaps xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [eax]
    vsubps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+16
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?vsa@@3UVec4@VMATH@@A
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+16
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+16, xmm0
    vsubps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+32
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+32
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+32, xmm0
    vsubps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+48
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+48
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+48, xmm0
    vsubps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+64
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
    vaddps  xmm4, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+64
    vmovaps xmm2, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+80
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+64, xmm4
    vmovaps xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [eax]
    vsubps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+96
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?vsa@@3UVec4@VMATH@@A
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+96
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+96, xmm0
    vsubps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+112
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+112
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+112, xmm0
    vsubps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+128
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+128
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+128, xmm0
    vsubps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+144
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+144
    vsubps  xmm2, xmm1, xmm0
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+144, xmm0
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm2, xmm4
    vsubps  xmm0, xmm1, xmm0
    vmulps  xmm1, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+224
    vmovdqu xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+176
    vmovdqu XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+192, xmm0
    vmovdqu xmm0, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+160
    vmovdqu XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+176, xmm0
    vmovdqu xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [eax]
    vmovdqu XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+160, xmm0
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm4, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+208
    vaddps  xmm1, xmm0, xmm1
    vmulps  xmm0, xmm2, XMMWORD PTR ?es@@3UEQSTATE@@A+240
    vaddps  xmm0, xmm1, xmm0
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR [ecx], xmm0
    mov eax, ecx
    pop ebp
    mov esp, ebx
    pop ebx
    ret 0
?TestEQ@@YA?AUVec4@VMATH@@PAUEQSTATE@@AAU12@@Z ENDP ; TestEQ
```

The produced assembly of the 2nd version is significantly longer and slower. It is not strictly related to *Visual Studio*, since *Clang 3.8* produces similar performance results.

---

Clang 3.8 generated assembly for the **1st version**:

```
"?TestEQ@@YAT__m128@@PAUEQSTATE@@AAT1@@Z": # @"\01?TestEQ@@YAT__m128@@PAUEQSTATE@@AAT1@@Z"
Lfunc_begin0:
Ltmp0:
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
    movl    8(%esp), %eax
    movl    4(%esp), %ecx
    vmovaps _vsa, %xmm0
    vmovaps (%ecx), %xmm1
    vmovaps 16(%ecx), %xmm2
    vmovaps (%eax), %xmm3
    vsubps  %xmm2, %xmm3, %xmm3
    vmulps  %xmm3, %xmm1, %xmm3
    vaddps  %xmm3, %xmm0, %xmm3
    vaddps  %xmm3, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vmovaps %xmm2, 16(%ecx)
    vmovaps 32(%ecx), %xmm3
    vsubps  %xmm3, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vmulps  %xmm2, %xmm1, %xmm2
    vaddps  %xmm2, %xmm3, %xmm2
    vmovaps %xmm2, 32(%ecx)
    vmovaps 48(%ecx), %xmm3
    vsubps  %xmm3, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vmulps  %xmm2, %xmm1, %xmm2
    vaddps  %xmm2, %xmm3, %xmm2
    vmovaps %xmm2, 48(%ecx)
    vmovaps 64(%ecx), %xmm3
    vsubps  %xmm3, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vmulps  %xmm2, %xmm1, %xmm1
    vaddps  %xmm1, %xmm3, %xmm1
    vmovaps %xmm1, 64(%ecx)
    vmovaps 80(%ecx), %xmm2
    vmovaps 96(%ecx), %xmm3
    vmovaps (%eax), %xmm4
    vsubps  %xmm3, %xmm4, %xmm4
    vmulps  %xmm4, %xmm2, %xmm4
    vaddps  %xmm4, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vaddps  %xmm0, %xmm3, %xmm0
    vmovaps %xmm0, 96(%ecx)
    vmovaps 112(%ecx), %xmm3
    vsubps  %xmm3, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vmulps  %xmm0, %xmm2, %xmm0
    vaddps  %xmm0, %xmm3, %xmm0
    vmovaps %xmm0, 112(%ecx)
    vmovaps 128(%ecx), %xmm3
    vsubps  %xmm3, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vmulps  %xmm0, %xmm2, %xmm0
    vaddps  %xmm0, %xmm3, %xmm0
    vmovaps %xmm0, 128(%ecx)
    vmovaps 144(%ecx), %xmm3
    vsubps  %xmm3, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vmulps  %xmm0, %xmm2, %xmm0
    vaddps  %xmm0, %xmm3, %xmm0
    vmovaps %xmm0, 144(%ecx)
    vmovaps 192(%ecx), %xmm2
    vsubps  %xmm0, %xmm2, %xmm0
    vaddps  %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm3
    vsubps  %xmm3, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vmulps  208(%ecx), %xmm1, %xmm1
    vmulps  224(%ecx), %xmm2, %xmm2
    vmulps  240(%ecx), %xmm0, %xmm0
    vmovaps 176(%ecx), %xmm3
    vmovaps %xmm3, 192(%ecx)
    vmovaps 160(%ecx), %xmm3
    vmovaps %xmm3, 176(%ecx)
    vmovaps (%eax), %xmm3
    vmovaps %xmm3, 160(%ecx)
    vaddps  %xmm2, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vaddps  %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm0
    retl
Lfunc_end0:
```

Clang 3.8 generated assembly for the **2nd version**:

```
"?TestEQ@@YA?AUVec4@@PAUEQSTATE@@AAU1@@Z": # @"\01?TestEQ@@YA?AUVec4@@PAUEQSTATE@@AAU1@@Z"
Lfunc_begin0:
Ltmp0:
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
    movl    12(%esp), %ecx
    movl    8(%esp), %edx
    vmovaps (%edx), %xmm0
    vmovaps 16(%edx), %xmm1
    vmovaps (%ecx), %xmm2
    vsubps  %xmm1, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vmulps  %xmm0, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vaddps  _vsa, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vaddps  %xmm2, %xmm1, %xmm1
    vmovaps %xmm1, 16(%edx)
    vmovaps 32(%edx), %xmm2
    vsubps  %xmm2, %xmm1, %xmm1
    vmulps  %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm1
    vaddps  %xmm1, %xmm2, %xmm1
    vmovaps %xmm1, 32(%edx)
    vmovaps 48(%edx), %xmm2
    vsubps  %xmm2, %xmm1, %xmm1
    vmulps  %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm1
    vaddps  %xmm1, %xmm2, %xmm1
    vmovaps %xmm1, 48(%edx)
    vmovaps 64(%edx), %xmm2
    vsubps  %xmm2, %xmm1, %xmm1
    vmulps  %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm0
    vaddps  %xmm0, %xmm2, %xmm0
    vmovaps %xmm0, 64(%edx)
    vmovaps 80(%edx), %xmm1
    vmovaps 96(%edx), %xmm2
    vmovaps (%ecx), %xmm3
    vsubps  %xmm2, %xmm3, %xmm3
    vmulps  %xmm1, %xmm3, %xmm3
    vaddps  _vsa, %xmm3, %xmm3
    vaddps  %xmm3, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vmovaps %xmm2, 96(%edx)
    vmovaps 112(%edx), %xmm3
    vsubps  %xmm3, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vmulps  %xmm1, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vaddps  %xmm2, %xmm3, %xmm2
    vmovaps %xmm2, 112(%edx)
    vmovaps 128(%edx), %xmm3
    vsubps  %xmm3, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vmulps  %xmm1, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vaddps  %xmm2, %xmm3, %xmm2
    vmovaps %xmm2, 128(%edx)
    vmovaps 144(%edx), %xmm3
    vsubps  %xmm3, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vmulps  %xmm1, %xmm2, %xmm1
    vaddps  %xmm1, %xmm3, %xmm1
    vmovaps %xmm1, 144(%edx)
    vmovaps 192(%edx), %xmm2
    vsubps  %xmm1, %xmm2, %xmm1
    vaddps  %xmm1, %xmm0, %xmm3
    vsubps  %xmm3, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vmulps  208(%edx), %xmm0, %xmm0
    vmulps  224(%edx), %xmm2, %xmm2
    movl    4(%esp), %eax
    vmulps  240(%edx), %xmm1, %xmm1
    vmovaps 176(%edx), %xmm3
    vmovaps %xmm3, 192(%edx)
    vmovaps 160(%edx), %xmm3
    vmovaps %xmm3, 176(%edx)
    vmovaps (%ecx), %xmm3
    vmovaps %xmm3, 160(%edx)
    vaddps  %xmm2, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vaddps  %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm0
    vmovaps %xmm0, (%eax)
    retl
Lfunc_end0:
```

Although the number of the instructions is the same, the 1st version is still about 50% faster.

---

I tried to identify the cause of the issue, without success. There are  suspicious things like those ugly `vmovdqu` instructions in the 2nd MSVC assembly. Construction, copy assignment operator and the pass-by-reference also can unnecessarily move the data from SSE registers back to memory, however all my attempts to solve or exactly identify the issue was unsuccessful.

I really don't think that such a simple wrapper cannot reach the same performance as the bare `__m128`, whatever causes the overhead it could be eliminated.

**So what is going on there?**

Comment: I have little experience with simd instructions. Can you elaborate a bit more on why one can't pass the arguments by value in the second example?

Comment: @MikeMB Because SSE data must be aligned to 16 byte boundaries. The encapsulated __m128 member enforce the alignment (properly) to Vec4. If I were pass it by value that would enforce the alignment to the function arguments too, which is not possible and leads to compilation error.

Comment: Looks like you test code got slightly mangled here: `es->f1p0  += (es->lf * (sample   - es->f1p0)) + vsa;vsa));` - if you can fix this I'll try the code with a couple of other compilers to see if the difference is compiler-specific.

Comment: @PaulR Yeah, I was just fixing it when you commented :) It's correct now.

Comment: I see no significant difference when trying with Clang 3.8, and GCC 6 produces a sequence of instructions of identical length as your first snippet.

Comment: I just tried clang and gcc but there are a bunch of errors with both that it's not obvious how to fix. If you can make the code a little more portable then I'll try it again.

Comment: What hardware did you test on?  Modern CPUs (Intel Nehalem and later, and AMD Bulldozer-family or maybe earlier) do `movdqu` loads/stores just as fast as `movdqa` when the data actually is aligned at run-time.  Re: portability: http://gcc.godbolt.org/ uses gcc/clang on Linux, so put your code up there with `-Wall -Wextra -O3 -mtune=haswell` to find all the errors and warnings from non-Windows compilers.  nvm, you say you already did.  Then post the godbolt link in your question, please :)  Either two links or a link with an `#ifdef`.

Comment: @PaulR what kind of errors? gcc.godbolt.org eats it without any problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes I test it on Intel Broadwell.

Comment: @plasmacel: errors like `error: conversion from 'const Vec4' to '__m128' (vector of 4 'float' values) is ambiguous` and `overloaded 'operator+=' must have at least one parameter of class or enumeration type` - let me check to make sure I haven't done something stupid (like miss out a required header).

Comment: Post your godbolt link(s) in the question to make sure everyone's looking at identical code.

Comment: I updated the quest with godbolt links. Interestingly the assembly is almost the same. Maybe the problem is related to MSVC.

Comment: What happens if you'll add "__declspec( align( 16 ) )" to your class?

Comment: I generated Clang 3.8 assembly listings on my machine, they are similar to the godbolt versions. Although the the number of the instructions is the same at the 1st and 2nd version, the 1st is still about 50% faster.

Comment: @Soonts I already tried, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Have you tried adding hints for leaving values in registers. You could also try replacing set with broadcast. The compiler could be arrive in a state where it didn't do this optimization. This will lead to less moves in the assembly.

Comment: @JensMunk what kind of hints do you mean? the register keyword? the set operation used outside the test loop, so that couldn't hit the performance.

Comment: @plasmacel: Strangely enough, pass-by-value seems to work for me (VS2015, x64) - at least it doesn't produce any compiler errors. But it doesn't seem to impact the performance.

Comment: The `register` keyword for hinting that variables should stay in register. Also try to replace `_mm_set_ps(f)` with `_mm_broadcast_ss((float*)&f)`. The compiler should be able to this optimization, but I may have failed. Sorry, could not download the code, so didn't see that.

Comment: @MikeMB could you upload the project files zipped to somewhere, then share the link with me? if I try to do what you I get `Error C2719: 'va': formal parameter with requested alignment of 16 won't be aligned`

Comment: @plasmacel You forgot to include the `using Vec4 = __m128` for CASE 2. It does not compile

Comment: @JensMunk Yes, I know about it. I already updated the link. Thanks for the catch btw.

Comment: @JensMunk: Taking the address of the float is more likely to force it into memory if the compiler is being silly.  Use `_mm_set1_ps(f)` instead of `_mm_set_ps(f,f,f,f)`.  It has the advantage of still compiling without AVX.  If the compile target *does* support AVX, both ways will compile to `vbroadcastss` if the value is in memory.  (Note that `vbroadcastss xmm, xmm` requires AVX2, only the load form is available in AVX1.  So if you compile for AVX1 without AVX2, you're more likely to get the compiler to store/broadcast-load instead of `vshufps` to broadcast from a register.)

Comment: I have never seen that. I usually use _mm_set_ps and if it is necessary my compiler introduces broadcast instructions but I can only speak for gcc and icc. I think the performance difference is due to additional moves so register hints in the right places may solve this

Comment: I'm close to the solution in MSVC. The performance hit comes from the call of the `TestEQ` function (and the associated moves). I didn't check the assembly yet, but the performance timings are identical when `TestEQ` is forced to inline (no function call). It seems that the compiler handle the function call and/or the passed arguments differently when one of them is the builtin `__m128`. I think when the passed arguments are user defined types MSVC don't apply these optimizations. The `__vectorcall` convention on `TestEQ` also speeds the things up.

Comment: @PeterCordes `mm_set1_ps` has nothing to do with avx, it just happens to be accelerated by `vbroadcast`. On older older cpus it loads one component then shuffles it across the vector. set1 was there long before avx existed.

Comment: The test kernel does `return(VAdd(l, VAdd(m, h)));`. Isn't that supposed to be using the commented out line above it?

Comment: @doug65536: exactly, that's why you should prefer `_mm_set1_ps` over `_mm_broadcast_ss`, esp. when you have a value already, not a pointer.  (gcc/clang don't usually have trouble optimizing away the dereference, but [icc13 does](https://godbolt.org/g/zJGTSI), @ Jens).

Comment: I suggest you look at the source code and read the documentation to [Agner Fog's Vector Cass Library](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass),

Comment: I just ran your code compiled with MSVC 2015 64-bit mode using `/O2` and I see see no significant difference between case 1 and 2 (I am using a Haswell system).

Comment: @Zboson It is because x64 mode uses different calling convention thus different optimizations made on the `TestEQ` function. The overhead came from the fact that the function pushed the SSE register to the stack. I will share the details soon.

Comment: I posted my answer in detail if any of you are interested in it.

Comment: clang will make Intel-syntax asm with `-masm=intel`.  It would be much better to show all the asm dumps in the same syntax.

Comment: Please note that Intel supplies these sorts of wrappers for VS, in the form of `dvec.h`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turned out the problem is not with the user defined `struct Vec4`.
It is deeply related to the x86 calling conventions.

The default x86 calling convention in Visual C++ is `__cdecl`, which

> Pushes parameters on the stack, in reverse order (right to left)

Now this is a problem, since `Vec4` should be kept and passed in an XMM register. But let's see what is actually happening.

---

### 1st case

In the first case `Vec4` is a simple type alias of `__m128`.

```
using Vec4 = __m128;
/* ... */
Vec4 TestEQ(EQSTATE* es, Vec4 &sample) { ... }
```

The generated function header of `TestEQ` in assembly is

```
?TestEQ@@YA?AT__m128@@PAUEQSTATE@@AAT1@@Z PROC      ; TestEQ, COMDAT
; _es$ = ecx
; _sample$ = edx
...
```

Nice.

---

### 2nd case

In the second case `Vec4` is not an alias of `__m128`, it is an user defined type now.

Here I investigate compilation for both x86 and x64 platform.

**x86 (32-bit compilation)**

Since `__cdecl` (which is the default calling convention in x86) doesn't allow to pass aligned values to functions (that would emit `Error C2719: 'sample': formal parameter with requested alignment of 16 won't be aligned`) we pass it by `const` reference.

```
struct Vec4{ __m128 simd; /* ... */ };
/* ... */
Vec4 TestEQ(EQSTATE* es, const Vec4 &sample) { ... }
```

which generates the function header for `TestEQ` as

```
?TestEQ@@YA?AUVec4@@PAUEQSTATE@@ABU1@@Z PROC        ; TestEQ, COMDAT
; ___$ReturnUdt$ = ecx
; _es$ = edx
    push    ebx
    mov ebx, esp
    sub esp, 8
    and esp, -8                 ; fffffff8H
    add esp, 4
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, DWORD PTR [ebx+4]
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _sample$[ebx]
    ...
```

This is not so simple like the one in the 1st case. The arguments are moved to the stack. There are some additional `mov` instructions between the first few SSE instructions too, which are not listed here. These instructions in overall are enough to somewhat hit the performance.

**x64 (64-bit compilation)**

Windows in x64 use a different calling convention as part of the *x64 Application Binary Interface (ABI)*.

This convention tries to keep the data in registers if possible, in a way that floating-point data kept in XMM registers.

From [MSDN Overview of x64 Calling Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx):

> The x64 Application Binary Interface (ABI) is a 4 register fast-call
>   calling convention, with stack-backing for those registers. There is a
>   strict one-to-one correspondence between arguments in a function, and
>   the registers for those arguments. Any argument that doesn’t fit in 8
>   bytes, or is not 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes, must be passed by reference.
>   (...)
>   All floating point operations are done using the 16 XMM registers.
>   The arguments are passed in registers RCX, RDX, R8, and R9. If the argumentsare
>   float/double, they are passed in XMM0L, XMM1L, XMM2L, and XMM3L. 16
>   byte arguments are passed by reference.

From [Wikipedia page for x86-64 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions)

> The Microsoft x64 calling convention is followed on Windows
>   and pre-boot UEFI (for long mode on x86-64). It uses registers RCX,
>   RDX, R8, R9 for the first four integer or pointer arguments (in that
>   order), and XMM0, XMM1, XMM2, XMM3 are used for floating point
>   arguments. Additional arguments are pushed onto the stack (right to
>   left). Integer return values (similar to x86) are returned in RAX if
>   64 bits or less. Floating point return values are returned in XMM0.

So the second case in x64 mode generates the function header for `TestEQ` as

```
?TestEQ@@YQ?AUVec4@@PAUEQSTATE@@ABU1@@Z PROC        ; TestEQ, COMDAT
; _es$ = ecx
; _sample$ = edx
...
```

This is exactly the same as the 1st case!

---

### Solution

For x86 mode the presented behavior should be clearly fixed.

The most simple solution is to `inline` the function.
Although this is just a hint and the compiler can completely ignore, you can tell the compiler to always inline the function. However sometimes this is not desired because of the function size or any other reason.

Fortunately Microsoft introduced the `__vectorcall` convention in Visual Studio 2013 and above (available in both x86 and x64 mode). This is very similar to the default Windows x64 calling convention, but with more utilizable registers.

Let's rewrite the 2nd case with `__vectorcall`:

```
Vec4 __vectorcall TestEQ(EQSTATE* es, const Vec4 &sample) { ... }
```

Now the generated assembly function header for `TestEQ` is

```
?TestEQ@@YQ?AUVec4@@PAUEQSTATE@@ABU1@@Z PROC        ; TestEQ, COMDAT
; _es$ = ecx
; _sample$ = edx
...
```

which is finally the same as the *1st case* and the *2nd case in x64*.

As Peter Cordes pointed out, to take the full advantage of `__vectorcall`, the `Vec4` argument should be passed by value, instead of constant reference. To do this the passed type should meet some requirements, like it must be trivially copy constructible (no user defined copy constructors) and shouldn't contain any union. More info in the comments below and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn375768.aspx).

### Final words

It looks like MSVC under the hood automatically applies the `__vectorcall` convention as an optimization when it detects an `__m128` argument. Otherwise it uses the default calling convention `__cdecl` (you can change this behavior by compiler options).

People told me in the comments that they didn't see much difference between the GCC and Clang generated assembly of the two case. This is because these compilers with optimization flag `-O2` simply inline the `TestEQ` function into the test loop body ([see](https://godbolt.org/g/fZ8X0N)). It is also possible that they would be more clever than MSVC and they would perform better optimization of the function call.

Comment: You realize that all the cases you've shown are passing a pointer to the data in memory, right?  Because you pass by reference, not by value.  Using `__vectorcall`, an arg passed by value would go in an `xmm0`.  You return by value, which happens in `xmm0` instead of in a hidden pointer.  (This is what bumps `const Vec4 &sample` up to being the 3rd arg, and thus the pointer is passed on the stack.  IDK why MSVC decides to align the stack to a multiple of 8 (not 16) in that case.  Anyway, **passing by ref is defeating the purpose of `__vectorcall` in the non-inline case.**

Comment: @PeterCordes `__vectorcall` will pass the data of the vector by reference anyway. "Any argument that doesn’t fit in 8 bytes, or is not 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes, must be passed by reference. 16 byte arguments are passed by reference." The performance timing also identical between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference.

Comment: That's not what [the official docs say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn375768.aspx):  "Floating-point and `__m128` types are passed in XMM registers".  That also confirms that structs containing only `__m128` vectors can be passed by value in XMM registers.  (They're called "Homogeneous Vector Aggregates", or HVAs).

Comment: @PeterCordes You are correct, I confused it with the default x64 calling convention. That passes `__m128` vectors by reference. And `__vectorcall` pass them by value. Anyway the overhead is solved by `__vectorcall` and pass-by-reference. Maybe `__vectorcall` change the alignment of the stack? I don't know. The instruction difference between `__vectorcall` pass-by-reference and `__vectorcall` pass-by-value is a single additional `movaps` in the case of pass-by-value.

Comment: `__vectorcall` may have made the performance of `__m128` and your struct the same, but *both* of them are slowed down by your use of pass-by-reference instead of pass-by-value.  The difference you showed in this answer is that `__vectorcall` allows the return value to be returned in a vector reg instead of in a pointer, since you still return by value.  I didn't read the docs carefully, but `__vectorcall` probably doesn't impose any extra alignment requirements.  A non-vectorcall function calling a vectorcall function would have to run a few extra insns to align the stack first.

Comment: @PeterCordes I must disagree. I can show you the generated assembly of the `__vectorcall` pass-by-reference and the `__vectorcall` pass-by-value. The pass-by-ref is shorter (less moves), and faster or not worse than the pass-by-value. I repeated the test with -O2, -O1 and -O0 too. At -O0 the pass-by-ref is faster, at -O1 and -O2 its not worse than pass-by-value. It's weird but true. I'm testing on Intel Broadwell.

Comment: Nobody cares about `-O0` speed, that's totally irrelevant.  If your vector is already in memory when you call the function, then passing a pointer and having `TestEQ` do the vector load is not much different from having the caller do the load.  I'm not surprised there's no measurable perf diff with your `main` calling `TestEQ`.  If the caller already had the vector live in a register, I'd certainly expect smaller code and slightly better performance from passing it in a register.

Comment: @PeterCordes That is possible yeah. However that slight slowdown in `__vectorcall` is still a speedup compared to `__cdecl`. And passing by const reference is more portable and universal. Even more that pass-by-value is allowed only on homogenouse vector aggregates in x86. If you have an user-defined constructor that's type is not a HVA anymore and you must stick to the const ref approach.

Comment: @PeterCordes I will update my answer with these details, thanks for your insights.

Comment: You still return by value (which is why `__vectorcall` is giving you a speedup in 32bit), so why not pass by value?  The official docs I linked earlier don't say anything about constructors or lack thereof.  Maybe you're thinking of POD types?  HVA isn't a subset or superset of POD, it's just different, at least according to MS's documentation in that page.  As far as "portable/universal": the SystemV ABI passes/returns vectors in vector regs, [so you get better code from passing by value there, too](https://godbolt.org/g/ZdDz55), in cases where a call doesn't inline.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110197/discussion-between-plasmacel-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: Why waste people's time with 32-bit mode? You only get half the SIMD registers in 32-bit mode. With AVX512 you only get a quarter of them.  MSFT clearly puts less emphasis on optimization for 32-bit mode.  See for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34784815/2542702) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34598756/2542702).

Comment: @Zboson It's not the first time I see you almost offending me or others because they have an issue with x86. The problems come themselves, independently that Zboson like them or not. And it's not your business to tell people what platform should they use. Even more if you know nothing about the underlying conditions. It's true that MSFT puts less effort to optimize in x86, and of course x64 is better, but this doesn't automatically mean that nobody will compile in x86 anymore.

Comment: It's fine to ask a question about 32-bit mode but you should precondition your question stating this because 32-bit mode is abnormal. I can't remember the last time that somebody asked a question involving SIMD with GCC or OSX for 32-bit mode. But your question never stated that the problem was for 32-bit mode.

Comment: I just read your answer and tried `__vectorcall`. It's a good answer. I suggest you change one of your tags to the question (perhaps optimization) to viscual-c++ because this question is really interesting for MSVC.

Comment: @PeterCordes, the last time I tried to pass a SSE/AVX by value with MSVC I got the error "error C2719: formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned".  So at least it used to be the case that with MSVC you had to pass by const reference. This (passing by const reference) should not be a problem anyway if the compiler is good enough. On the other hand it's only MSVC that does not let you pass by value.

Comment: @Zboson Good idea. I just updated it based on Peter Cordes' comments. I can confirm that pass-by-value works in MSVC with x86 `__vectorcall`, x64 `__vectorcall` and the default x64 calling convention. However it can fail in x86 if the type is not a Homogenous Vector Aggregate. The MSDN docs don't dive too deep into the details, but based on my experiments the type must be trivially copy constructible and shouldn't contain any unions.

Comment: I tried pass by value with x64 without __vectorcall and it does not pass by value (but it does compile) and instead passes a pointer.  It does pass by value with  __vectorcall.  However, this was for non-inlined function. As long as you declare your functions inline in a header this should not be a problem.  x32 however did pass by value even without __vectorcall. This is strange.  I tried `__m128 foo(__m128 x, __m128 y) { return _mm_add_ps(x,y); }` and comiled with `cl /c /O2 /FA foo.cpp` (I have two scripts which set up the command line for 32 and 64 bit compiling).

Comment: @Zboson I forgot to mention that the x64 calling convention passes arguments by pointer if they are larger than 8 bytes. Up to 8 bytes it passes by value. So this behavior is ok. However how could you pass an aligned data by value in x86 without `__vectorcall`? Because it looks like that for `__m128` arguments MSVC automatically applies a `__vectorcall`. If you try the same with a wrapper struct, you get a compilation error.

Comment: Yes, with a wrapper struct you can't pass by value without `__vectorcall` for 32-bit mode.  What you can do is compile with `/Gv` which uses the `__vectorcall` calling conventions.  You can use this with const reference, it still passes a pointer but like 64-bit mode.  Then your wrapper struct will support 32-bit mode and 64-bit mode and work for MSVC before 2013 but will be optimized for MSVC2013 and up.  Another alternative is to use `/Gv` and pass by value. This will also work for 32-bit mode and 64-bit mode as well but then your vector library will only work for MSVC2013 and up.

Comment: I was wrong to be so dismissive of your question. Despite the fact that the performance hit manifest itself in 32-bit mode `__vectorcall` is interesting for 64-bit mode as well and I only learned about this because of your question. My main frustration applies to MSFT and that MSVC (through the gui) still defaults to 32-bit mode and that the compiler sucks in many ways compared to GCC and Clang (I rarely use MSVC anymore).