# Inline functions and calling conventions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inline, simd, calling-convention

Is there a point in specifying calling convention for an inline function? For example, I am writing SIMD math library, where it is recommended to use `__vectorcall`, but all of my functions are inline. In some articles I have seen people inlining all function and still saying, that you need to compile the library with default `__vectorcall` convention (or actually putting this attribute).
 I can see the difference in assembly, when function is not inline. But what is the point to specify calling convention for inline function since it is not really a function call? Isn't it better to specify `__vectorcall` only for not inline function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36852518/2542702

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inline keyword is only a suggestion to the compiler; it doesn't guarantee that the function will be inlined. For example, a recursive function can't be inlined, and if you use function pointers the compiler may need to generate non-inline copies of otherwise inlined functions. Additionally, constraints on memory and space might stop the compiler from inlining a function.

As a result, even if you mark a function inline, you'll still to specify a calling convention if appropriate because there's no guarantee that the compiler will indeed eliminate the function call.

Comment: "recursive function can't be inlined" if compiler will be able to optimise recursion into iteration, it can be inlined. If compiler will be able to predict recursion depth at compile time, it can be unrolled and inlined...

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot That's true, though in general there's no way for a compiler to do that (thanks, Halting Problem!) Do you know of any compilers that do this in cases other than tail call elimination?

Comment: Both GCC and Clang try hard to transform not-quite-tail-recursion into iteration. I do not have evidence of even partially inlining non-optimizable recursive functions

Comment: [DirectXMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath) is an all inline header, but as noted here depending on the context of the function and other factors the compiler doesn't always inline the body of the function. Therefore, when it does end up doing a function call I want it to be as efficient as possible. x86 ``__fastcall`` can pass up to three SIMD values in register, but x64's standard convention won't pass any. That's why I suggested MSVC implement ``__vectorcall`` in the first place. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418728.aspx#Call_Conventions)