# __attribute__ ((vector_size)) magic being destroyed by union

Tags: c, gcc, clang, simd, avx

Using godbolt.org `x86-64 gcc 11.2`, This code...

```c
typedef int v4i __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));

typedef union {
    v4i v;
} int4;

int4 mul(int4 l, int4 r)
{
    return (int4){.v=l.v * r.v};
}
```

...produces this assembly (when compiled with `-O3 -mavx`)...

```
mul:
        vpmulld xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
        ret
```

However this code...

```c
typedef int v4i __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));

typedef union {
    v4i v;
    struct {int x,y,z,w;}; // this line is the change
    int i[4]; // this one too
} int4;

int4 mul(int4 l, int4 r)
{
    return (int4){.v=l.v * r.v};
}
```

...produces this assembly (when also compiled with `-O3 -mavx`)...

```
mul:
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-40], rdi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-32], rsi
        vmovdqa xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rsp-40]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-24], rdx
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-16], rcx
        vpmulld xmm0, xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rsp-24]
        vmovdqa XMMWORD PTR [rsp-40], xmm0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp-40]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp-32]
        ret
```

`x86-64 clang 13.0.1` has similar results

So my question is, how can I convince gcc (and/or clang) that these 2 blocks of code should produce the same output?

I've tried `__attribute__ ((aligned))`, removing the `int i[4];` or the `struct`, applying `__attribute__ ((packed))` to the `struct`, I even gave `__attribute__ ((transparent_union))` a go. Whatever magic status `__attribute__ ((vector_size (16)))` bestows is broken by adding anything to the `union`.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [SSE vector wrapper type performance compared to bare \_\_m128](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36833462) but that's talking about 32-bit mode Windows calling conventions, not x86-64 System V.  Related: [What is the calling convention for floating-point values in C for x86\_64 in System V?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57859857) and also [C++ operator\[\] access to elements of SIMD (e.g. AVX) variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64282775)

Answer (score 0):

I should say that I have never worked with this attribute personally and I checked the gcc just now, but from document I saw something that I think will be useful for your problem.

From your code, I can assume that you want to use `union` to access each `int` of vector separately. But if it is the only reason, it is not necessary to use `int[4]` or `struct {int x,y,z,w;};` as part of union, because vectors can be used like arrays themselves:

```
typedef int v4i __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));

typedef union {
    v4i v;
} int4;

int4 mul(int4 l, int4 r)
{
    int4 ret = (int4){.v=l.v * r.v};
    printf("%i %i %i %i", ret.v[0], ret.v[1], ret.v[2], ret.v[3]);
    return ret;
}
```

and the code will be optimized as you like. In addition, if you need byte level access, `union` with another vector works as you like too:

```
typedef int v4i __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));
typedef unsigned char v4b __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));

struct i4s{int x,y,z,w;};

typedef union {
    v4i v;
    v4b v2;
} int4;

int4 mul(int4 l, int4 r)
{
    return (int4){.v=l.v * r.v};
}
```

It seems that `union` will work with primitive-like types in this case. for example even `__m128i` works too.

Comment: The code presented is a minimalist example of a much larger chain of similar unions, with as far as is practical, GLSL style swizzling into smaller types. For example, there is a `struct { int2 xy, zw;};` and `struct { int3 xyz; int __w2; };`. Also `__m128i` isn't an option as there is no `_mm128i_mul_epi32()` function. That and wintel isn't the only platform with SIMD capability. It is however a useful yard-stick of compiler capability, features working here will sooner or later work on ARM and friends (if they don't already).

Comment: @burito: Wintel?  If you're worried about Windows, look at its calling convention (`__attribute__((ms_abi))` or vectorcall), since it has different rules for union passing than GNU C. (Without vectocall it will never pass a 16-byte vector in an XMM reg even for a bare `vri`).  Unless you plan to use `__attribute__((sysv_abi))` in your code even when targeting Windows.  But really, most of these tiny functions should inline, so it's not necessarily a showstopper.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, they are the same. For some reason the second one includes the populating the xmm? registers from the stack, but if for example one adds a main function...

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // volatile keyword added so they don't get optimised out   
    volatile int4 x = {.v={1,2,3,4}};
    volatile int4 y = {.v={1,2,3,4}};
    int4 z = mul(x, y);
    
    return z.v[0];
}
```

...then the function (or single `vpmulld` instruction in this case) gets inlined, and different, appropriate stack manipulation gets inserted.

Comment: It's not "from the stack", it's from RSI:RDI function args, just happening to use a silly strategy involving the stack.  The calling convention passes a 16-byte union in integer regs unless it contains *only* a SIMD vector (type SSE or SSEUPPER in the x86-64 SysV ABI doc).

Comment: I think I should rewrite my question as "hey I don't understand what these instructions are here for". Thank you for answering the question I didn't know I was asking, and providing some very helpful links to set me on the path!