# Compiler is not producing FMA instructions for simple loop compiled for AVX512 CPU

Tags: c++, gcc, vectorization, avx, avx512

With an implicit loop-vectorization experiment, GCC 11.2 does not produce fma instructions but only packed add and packed multiply instructions:

https://godbolt.org/z/srbfWMEG6

Sample code for testing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;

constexpr int frames=20;
constexpr float width = 2000;
constexpr float height = 2000;
constexpr int grainSize=width/4; // pixels
void createImage();
int getPoint(int x, int y);

/*
 * VectorizedKernel.h
 *
 *  Created on: Apr 16, 2022
 *      Author: tugrul
 */

#ifndef VECTORIZEDKERNEL_H_
#define VECTORIZEDKERNEL_H_



#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include<cmath>


namespace Vectorization
{

    template<typename Type, int Simd>
    struct KernelData
    {
        alignas(32)
        Type data[Simd];

        KernelData(){}

        KernelData(const Type broadcastedInit)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                data[i] = broadcastedInit;
            }
        }

        KernelData(const KernelData<Type,Simd> & vectorizedIit)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                data[i] = vectorizedIit.data[i];
            }
        }


        inline void readFrom(const Type * const __restrict__ ptr) noexcept
        {

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                data[i] = ptr[i];
            }
        }

        inline void writeTo(Type * const __restrict__ ptr) const noexcept
        {

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                ptr[i] = data[i];
            }
        }

        inline void writeTo(Type * const __restrict__ ptr, const KernelData<int,Simd> vec) const noexcept
        {

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                ptr[vec.data[i]] = data[i];
            }
        }

        template<typename F>
        inline void idCompute(const int id, const F & f) noexcept
        {

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                data[i] = f(id+i);
            }
        }

        // bool
        inline KernelData<int,Simd> lessThan(const KernelData<Type,Simd> vec) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<int,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i]<vec.data[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        // bool
        inline KernelData<int,Simd> lessThanOrEquals(const KernelData<Type,Simd> vec) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<int,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i]<=vec.data[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        // bool
        inline KernelData<int,Simd> lessThanOrEquals(const Type val) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<int,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i]<=val;
            }
            return result;
        }

        // bool
        inline KernelData<int,Simd> greaterThan(const KernelData<Type,Simd> vec) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<int,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i]>vec.data[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        // bool
        inline KernelData<int,Simd> greaterThan(const Type val) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<int,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i]>val;
            }
            return result;
        }

        // bool
        inline KernelData<int,Simd> equals(const KernelData<Type,Simd> vec) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<int,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i] == vec.data[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        // bool
        inline KernelData<int,Simd> equals(const Type val) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<int,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i] == val;
            }
            return result;
        }

        // bool
        inline KernelData<int,Simd> notEqual(const KernelData<Type,Simd> vec) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<int,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i] != vec.data[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        // bool
        inline KernelData<int,Simd> notEqual(const Type val) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<int,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i] != val;
            }
            return result;
        }


        // bool
        inline KernelData<int,Simd> logicalAnd(const KernelData<int,Simd> vec) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<int,Simd> result;


            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i] && vec.data[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        // bool
        inline KernelData<int,Simd> logicalOr(const KernelData<int,Simd> vec) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<int,Simd> result;


            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i] || vec.data[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        inline bool areAllTrue() const noexcept
        {
            bool result = true;


            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result = result && data[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        inline bool isAnyTrue() const noexcept
        {
            bool result = false;


            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result = result || data[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        template<typename ComparedType>
        inline const KernelData<ComparedType,Simd> ternary(const KernelData<ComparedType,Simd> vec1, const KernelData<ComparedType,Simd> vec2) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<ComparedType,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i]?vec1.data[i]:vec2.data[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        template<typename ComparedType>
        inline const KernelData<ComparedType,Simd> ternary(const ComparedType val1, const ComparedType val2) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<ComparedType,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i]?val1:val2;
            }
            return result;
        }

        inline void broadcast(const Type val) noexcept
        {

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                data[i] = val;
            }
        }

        inline void readFrom(const KernelData<Type,Simd> vec) noexcept
        {

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                data[i] = vec.data[i];
            }
        }

        template<typename NewType>
        inline const KernelData<NewType,Simd> cast() const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<NewType,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = (NewType)data[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        inline const KernelData<Type,Simd> sqrt() const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<Type,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = std::sqrt(data[i]);
            }
            return result;
        }

        inline const KernelData<Type,Simd> add(const KernelData<Type,Simd> vec) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<Type,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i] + vec.data[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        inline const KernelData<Type,Simd> sub(const KernelData<Type,Simd> vec) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<Type,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i] - vec.data[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        inline const KernelData<Type,Simd> div(const KernelData<Type,Simd> vec) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<Type,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i] / vec.data[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        inline const KernelData<Type,Simd> div(const Type val) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<Type,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i] / val;
            }
            return result;
        }



        inline const KernelData<Type,Simd> mul(const KernelData<Type,Simd> vec) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<Type,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i] * vec.data[i]; 
            }
            return result;
        }

        // returns current vector * vec1 + vec2
        inline const KernelData<Type,Simd> fusedMultiplyAdd(const KernelData<Type,Simd> vec1, const KernelData<Type,Simd> vec2) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<Type,Simd> result;
            
            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i] * vec1.data[i] + vec2.data[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        // returns current vector * vec1 - vec2
        inline const KernelData<Type,Simd> fusedMultiplySub(const KernelData<Type,Simd> vec1, const KernelData<Type,Simd> vec2) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<Type,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i] * vec1.data[i] - vec2.data[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        inline const KernelData<Type,Simd> mul(const Type val) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<Type,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i] * val;
            }
            return result;
        }

        inline const KernelData<Type,Simd> modulus(const KernelData<Type,Simd> vec) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<Type,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i] % vec.data[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        inline const KernelData<Type,Simd> modulus(const Type val) const noexcept
        {
            KernelData<Type,Simd> result;

            for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
            {
                result.data[i] = data[i] % val;
            }
            return result;
        }
    };




    template<int mask>
    struct KernelDataFactory
    {
        KernelDataFactory():width(mask)
        {

        }


        template<typename Type>
        inline
        KernelData<Type,mask> generate() const
        {
            return KernelData<Type,mask>();
        }


        template<typename Type>
        inline
        KernelData<Type,mask> generate(const KernelData<Type,mask> & vec) const
        {
            return KernelData<Type,mask>(vec);
        }


        template<typename Type>
        inline
        KernelData<Type,mask> generate(const Type & val) const
        {
            return KernelData<Type,mask>(val);
        }
        const int width;
    };


    template<class...Args>
    struct KernelArgs
    {};

    template<int SimdWidth, typename F, typename... Args>
    class Kernel
    {
    public:


        Kernel(F&& kernelPrm):kernel(std::move(kernelPrm))
        {

        }


        void run(int n, Args... args)
        {
            const int nLoop = (n/SimdWidth);
            const KernelDataFactory<SimdWidth> factory;
            for(int i=0;i<nLoop;i++)
            {
                auto id = factory.template generate<int>();
                id.idCompute(i*SimdWidth,[](const int prm){ return prm;});
                kernel(factory, id, args...);
            }



            if((n/SimdWidth)*SimdWidth != n)
            {
                const KernelDataFactory<1> factoryLast;

                const int m = n%SimdWidth;
                for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
                {
                    auto id = factoryLast.template generate<int>();
                    id.idCompute(nLoop*SimdWidth+i,[](const int prm){ return prm;});
                    kernel(factoryLast, id, args...);
                }
            }
        }
    private:
        F kernel;
    };

    template<int SimdWidth, typename F, class...Args>
    auto createKernel(F&& kernelPrm, KernelArgs<Args...> const& _prm_)
    {
        return Kernel<SimdWidth, F, Args...>(std::forward<F>(kernelPrm));
    }

}


#endif /* VECTORIZEDKERNEL_H_ */

int main()
{
    createImage();

    return 0;
}


#include <stdint.h>  // <cstdint> is preferred in C++, but stdint.h works.

#ifdef _MSC_VER
# include <intrin.h>
#else
# include <x86intrin.h>
#endif

// optional wrapper if you don't want to just use __rdtsc() everywhere
inline
uint64_t readTSC() {
    // _mm_lfence();  // optionally wait for earlier insns to retire before reading the clock
    uint64_t tsc = __rdtsc();
    // _mm_lfence();  // optionally block later instructions until rdtsc retires
    return tsc;
}
void createImage()
{

    std::vector<int> img(height*width);


    // compute single-thread "scalar" CPU
    /*
    for (size_t i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            img[j+i*width]= getPoint(i, j);
        }
    }
     */

    // single-thread vectorized
    constexpr int simd = 64;
    auto kernel = Vectorization::createKernel<simd>([&](auto & factory, auto & idThread, int * img){



        const auto j = idThread.modulus(width);
        const auto i = idThread.div(width);
        const int vecWidth = factory.width;



        auto x0 = j.template cast<float>();
        auto y0 = i.template cast<float>();

        const auto heightDiv2 = factory.template generate<float>(height/2.0f);

        const auto x = x0.sub(width/2.0f).sub(width/4.0f).div(width/3.0f);
        const auto y = heightDiv2.sub(y0).div(width/3.0f);


        const auto imagc = factory.template generate<float>(y);
        const auto realc = factory.template generate<float>(x);



        auto imagz = factory.template generate<float>(0);
        auto realz = factory.template generate<float>(0);


        // loop
        bool anyTrue = true;
        auto iteration = factory.template generate<int>(0);
        const auto iterationLimit = factory.template generate<int>(35);
        const auto one = factory.template generate<int>(1);
        const auto zero = factory.template generate<int>(0);
        const auto four = factory.template generate<float>(4.0f);
        while(anyTrue)
        {

            // computing while loop condition start
            const auto absLessThan2 = realz.mul(realz).add(imagz.mul(imagz)).lessThan(4.0f);
            const auto whileLoopCondition = absLessThan2.logicalAnd(iteration.lessThanOrEquals(35));
            anyTrue = whileLoopCondition.isAnyTrue();
            // computing while loop condition end


            // do complex multiplication z = z*z + c
            const auto zzReal = realz.fusedMultiplySub(realz,imagz.mul(imagz));
            const auto zzImag = realz.fusedMultiplyAdd(imagz,imagz.mul(realz));

            // if a lane has completed work, do not modify it
            realz = whileLoopCondition.ternary( zzReal.add(realc), realz);
            imagz = whileLoopCondition.ternary( zzImag.add(imagc), imagz);


            // increment iteration
            iteration = iteration.add(whileLoopCondition.ternary(1,0)); // todo: ternary increment


        }

        const auto thirtyFour = factory.template generate<int>(34);


        const auto ifLessThanThirtyFour = iteration.lessThan(thirtyFour);

        const auto conditionalValue1 = iteration.mul(255).div(33);
        const auto conditionalValue2 = factory.template generate<int>(0);

        const auto returnValue       = ifLessThanThirtyFour.ternary(conditionalValue1, conditionalValue2);
        const auto writeAddr = j.add(i.mul(width));

        returnValue.writeTo(img,writeAddr);

    },Vectorization::KernelArgs<int*>{});

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        auto t1 = readTSC();
        kernel.run(width*height,img.data());
        auto t2 = readTSC();
        std::cout<<(t2-t1)/(width*height)<<" cycles per pixel"<<std::endl;
    }
    // create string
    stringstream sstr;
    sstr << "P3" << endl << width << " " << height << endl << 255 << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            sstr << img[j+i*width] << " 0 0" << endl;
        }
    }

    // write to file at once
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("mandelbrot.ppm");
    if (fout.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File is opened!" << endl;
        fout << sstr.str();
        fout.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Could not open the file!" << endl;
    }
}

int getPoint(int a, int b)
{
    float x = static_cast<float>(b);
    float y = static_cast<float>(a);
    x = (x - width / 2 - width/4)/(width/3);
    y = (height / 2 - y)/(width/3);


    complex<float> c (x,y);

    complex <float> z(0, 0);
    size_t iter = 0;
    while (abs(z) < 2 && iter <= 35)
    {
        z = z * z + c;
        iter++;
    }
    if (iter < 34) return iter*255/33;
    else return 0;
}
```

What I tried to make it produce any kind of fma instruction:

- change -mprefer-vector-width=512 to 256 to 128
- change -march=native to cascadelake to skylake-avx512
- change -mavx512f to -mavx512bw

but all produced just add and mul instructions in vectorized form.

Is there an instrinsicless way to tell GCC or any other compiler to "produce fma for this line of code" by simple annotations (to let it use any instruction set SSE/AVX/AVX2/AVX512/... with readability)?

The specific function observed is this:

```
// returns current vector * vec1 + vec2
inline const KernelData<Type,Simd> fusedMultiplyAdd(const KernelData<Type,Simd> vec1, const KernelData<Type,Simd> vec2) const noexcept
{
    KernelData<Type,Simd> result;
    
    for(int i=0;i<Simd;i++)
    {
        result.data[i] = data[i] * vec1.data[i] + vec2.data[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

The test code produces a file containing ppm formatted mandelbrot image. It does the computation in vectorized form, similar to CUDA/OpenCL and gives speedup of around 10x-16x (depends on godbolt server's load) and I think FMA can speed it up more.

Comment: The GCC default is `-ffp-contract=fast` (and even "on" would allow it here, only contraction within a single expression is happening).  GCC does vectorize loops over FP arrays with FMA, like https://godbolt.org/z/3Kfono44K which has to check for overlap due to lack of `restrict`.  Is `result` a different type than the inputs or something?  Your full code is nowhere near minimal as a [mcve], and the simple function you quoted should normally vectorize with FMA.  Is your code maybe using more indirection that makes an overlap check harder?

Comment: Aren't plain arrays in a struct already __restrict__? Sometimes I call them like two.mul(two) so both can be same arrays.

Comment: When I add assertion, it found same vectors in 2 parameters in compile-time.  This must be only way to stop users putting same vector twice.

Comment: Ok, it was the 64 iterations of loop was not enough. When I test like you did with 10240 (and additional restricts), it used fma.

Comment: That's odd.  It's worthwhile to use FMA even for a single vector.  Also, IDK why `restrict` would matter; if it can vectorize at all with `vmulps` / `vaddps`, it can vectorize with FMA.   In my simpler test case, reducing it to 64 or 32 iterations still vectorizes with FMA, fully unrolling the loop and using 4 or 2x ZMM vectors: https://godbolt.org/z/oes84v4Y9  And using scalar FMA in the fallback loop for the overlap case.  Maybe you've found a missed-optimization for GCC where some complicated case interferes with contraction into FMA.  Does using math.h `fma(a,b,c)` help?

Comment: It looks like math.h ```fma(a,b,c)``` works because it produces fmsub instruction that is not linked to the source code by godbolt (I guess it links to math.h source) and the run-time improves a bit.