# Comparation of sum of square roots

Tags: c++, sqrt

I have MinGW GCC 4.8.1 and the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double eval(int a, int b){
    return std::sqrt(a) + std::sqrt(b);
}

int main(){
    double first = eval(545, 331);
    double second = eval(545, 331);

    if(first < second)
        std::cout << "first <  second" << std::endl;
    if(first == second)
        std::cout << "first == second" << std::endl;
    if(first > second)
        std::cout << "first >  second" << std::endl;
}
```

If compiled with `-O0`, the program prints the expected result:

```
first == second
```

However, if compiled with `-O1`, `-O2` or `-O3`, the program prints: (the result on [ideone](http://ideone.com/tSSM47))

```
first <  second
first == second
```

Why? How to fix it?

Comment: On coliru [it prints](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0faa177acceb3caa) `first == second` for all four flags (using clang).

Comment: With QtCreator 3.0.0, I got the same wrong result for MinGW 4.8 while MSVC 2012 32bits and 64 bits work fine in release mode. All Debug configurations work though. Strange.

Comment: Also, printing first and second seems to change the results depending on whether they are printed before, or after the comparisons.

Comment: Solution found: [Is this an g++ optimization bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517588/is-this-an-g-optimization-bug)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In x86 Architectures the precision of floating point is 80-bit but a `double` has only 64-bit. And with GCC Optimization evaluating an expression resulting a floating number and storing it on a `double` can result different values since the optimization changes how the floating number get adjusted to less precision.

To get the same result with different GCC Otimizations use `-ffloat-store` option.