# Rounding a double number up to the tenths place

Tags: c++, double, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [round() for float in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c)

Ok suppose I had the number `8.47434`. I want to round it up to 8.5 and to 1 decimal place. How would I go about doing this in C++

Comment: For a quick and dirty solution, you might want to read specifically [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c/2249412#2249412).

Answer (score 4):

Multiply by `10`, round and divide by `10` again.

Example:

```
round(10 * 8.47434f) / 10;
```

**Edit:**

OK, I just found out that `round()` is not always present in `math.h`.

The above works in gcc and icl (with Microsoft's libraries), but not in tcc.

`floor()`, however, is part of the standard libraries. So to round, we can add `0.5` and use `floor()`.

Example:

```
floor(10 * 8.47434f + 0.5f) / 10;
```

Comment: lacks several degrees of nuance, IMO

Comment: You may, actually definitely **will** lose precision by multiplying by 10 and edge cases will round the wrong way

Answer (score 3):

`std::floor(d)+std::floor((d-std::floor(d))*10.0+0.5)/10.0`

Doing it this way won't lose precision, as opposed to the other answers which multiply the original double by 10. (`d` would be your number by the way)

Be forewarned though: floating point numbers can't represent *anything*. With doubles: `1.35` will round to `1.3999999999999999`; `123.34` will be represented as `123.34999999999999` in the first place causing it to round down to `123.3` instead of the intended `123.4`; etc

Comment: Your examples seem wrong, I think your most recent edit changed the wrong `5`->`4`

Answer (score 0):

You could multiple by 10 add 0.5 cast to an int and divide by ten.

if the number is negative subtract 0.5 or multiply and divide by negative ten.