# Round off in JAVA

Tags: java

I want to round off a value for ex:

> 12.166666     ---->  12.00
>
> 12.49999      ---->  12.00
>
> 12.5111       ---->  13.00
>
> 12.9999       ---->  13.00

I want to to round off wrt 50 paise.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=round+a+number+in+javascript&sugexp=chrome,mod=4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is your friend.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902968/why-does-math-round0-49999999999999994-return-1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can take a look at the [`Math.round(double a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) method.

```
System.out.println(Math.round(12.51));//Yields 13
System.out.println(Math.round(12.49));//Yields 12
System.out.println(Math.round(12.50));//Yields 13
```

Comment: This can lead to [surprises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902968/why-does-math-round0-49999999999999994-return-1?lq=1) sometimes.

Comment: @Jesper: Very interesting. According to the [bug report](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6430675) though it has been fixed in Java 7. Although I do not know what version is the OP running, he/she could always upgrade their environment to go around this problem.

Comment: I just want to know why System.out.println(Math.round(12.49));//Yields 12 become 12?
It also should become 13.
Why its happen

Comment: @MilindaBandara: Anything less than 12.5 will be rounded down to 12. That being said, the `Math.ceil(double a)` method will yield the next largest integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.round` . For documentation  take a look at: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)