# How to round the double value in Java

Tags: java

I have tried to make the double value as round to the 2 precision values.I got it by using Date Format, but it is in String.
How to make the double value as round to the precision without using Date Format.

Comment: Please provide your code in question...

Comment: Do you want to round the printed value (for display purposes) or the variable itself (for calculation purposes)

Comment: share your scenario plz , do you want something like this ??http://stackoverflow.com/a/12190890/1283215

Comment: Maybe BigDecimal is your choise? Doubles are not very good with true rounding.

Answer (score 1):

here is the example

```
public class RoundValue 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   

    double kilobytes = 1205.6358;

    System.out.println("kilobytes : " + kilobytes);

    double newKB = Math.round(kilobytes*100.0)/100.0;
    System.out.println("kilobytes (Math.round) : " + newKB);

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
    System.out.println("kilobytes (DecimalFormat) : " + df.format(kilobytes));
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
kilobytes : 1205.6358
kilobytes (Math.round) : 1205.64
kilobytes (DecimalFormat) : 1205.64
```

Comment: Does not round, so not an answer, and the technique [does not work in general](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12684082/207421).

Answer (score 0):

As EJP and Leonidos said in comments, proper rounding is performed through the [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class not the `double` [primitive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Carefully choose your [rounding mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html). [Banker's Rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) is a common way to break ties (even splits), though the best way depends on your purpose and situation.

```
double d = 7.345;
java.math.BigDecimal bigDecimal = new java.math.BigDecimal(d).setScale(2, java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
System.out.println("My big decimal is: " + bigDecimal ); // Outputs: 7.34 (using Banker's Rounding)
```

See: [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)