# Round up a float number that has a non-zero decimal digit

Tags: c, rounding, ceil

I was asking about round a number half up earlier today and got great help from @alk. In that post, my thinking was to round up 4.5 to 5 but round 4.4 down to 4. And the solution given by @alk was:

```
int round_number(float x)
{
 return x + 0.5;
}
```

and it works very elegantly!

In this post, I would like to discuss how to implement the `ceil()` function in C.
Along the same line as the last solution given by @alk, I came up with the following:

```
int round_up(float y)
{
   return y + 0.99999999;
}
```

This works for all situations except when the the float number y has .00000001. I am wondering if there's any better way to do the same thing as `ceil()` in C.

Comment: You question asked how to **round up** then in the content you said **ceil()** function. That's completely different. You should edit it

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this reliably without getting in bed with the floating point format.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you reliably know the epsilon of float (I'm not sure standard C provides that), I think you're stuck with `return (y < 0 || y == (int)y) ? y : y + 1;`

Comment: Good catch; I've modified slightly to handle negative values.

Answer (score 1):

This fails for negative numbers.

```
int round_up(float y) {
 return y + 0.99999999;
}
```

But let's use that to our advantage.  `float` to `int` conversion is a truncate toward 0.0.  Thus negative numbers are doing a "round up" or "ceiling" function.  When we have a positive `float`, convert to `int` noting this is a "floor" function.  Adjust when `y` is not an integer.

(Assume `y` within `INT_MIN ... INT_MAX`.)

```
int ceil(float y) {
   if (y < 0) {
     return y;  // this does a ceiling function as y < 0.
   }
   int i = y; // this does a floor function as y >= 0.
   if (i != y) i++;
   return i;
 }

void ceil_test(float y) {
   printf("%f %d\n", y, ceil(y));
}
```

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc The ceiling of -2.5 is -2, not -1.

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet works incorrectly for negative numbers. -3.5 will be come -3, not -4. To round values properly use

```
int round_number(float x)
{
    if (x >= 0)
        return x + 0.5f;
    else
        return x - 0.5f
}
```

Even that way it's still incorrect for 2 values. See [Why does Math.round(0.49999999999999994) return 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9902968/995714). Note that you need to use the `f` suffix to get the `float` literal, otherwise the operation will be done in `double` precision and then downcast back to `float`

For ceiling, adding 1 is enough

```
int ceiling(float x)
{
    if (x < 0 || (int)x == x)
        return x;
    else
        return x + 1.0f;
}
```

When x is an integer, e.g. x = 3.0 (or -3.0), it returns 3 (or -3). For x = 3.1 it returns 4, for x = -3.1 it returns -3