# rounding up negative floating literal - java

Tags: java

Why does -0.5 when being passed on the Math.round results to 0? and 0.5 when being passed also results to 1? shouldn't it be that when you pass -0.5 to Math.round() should also produce -1 as result? I obtained the -1 result when the number was -0.6.

Answer (score 1):

[`Math.round(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-) is documented as:

> Returns the closest long to the argument, with ties rounding to positive infinity.

So -0.5 is rounding *up* (towards positive infinite) instead of *down* towards negative infinity. It's behaving exactly as documented.

Answer (score 1):

The working of round( x ) is implemented as floor( x + 0.5 ) until Java6 atleast.
So, by that logic, floor(-0.5 + 0.5) gives you 0
and
floor(0.5+0.5) gives you 1

You can refer this link for more details

[Why does Math.round(0.49999999999999994) return 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902968/why-does-math-round0-49999999999999994-return-1)

Answer (score 0):

If you read [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29), it says that `round()` "returns the closest long to the argument, with ties rounding up."

"Up" is towards positive infinity, not away from 0.

**ETA**: I see from Jon Skeet's answer that Java 8 docs improved the clarity on this. This answer quotes Java 7, which is bit more confusing than what 8 says.