# Different Rounding Results in Java 6 and Java 8

Tags: java, rounding-error

I am rewriting an old Java 6 Program written to perform some scientific calculations in Java 8 and stuck up in this situation where I'm getting different results for rounding operation.

Java 6 is rounding an input like `0.499999999999999999994` to `1` but Java 8 is making it `0`. I'm not able to understand the problem here.

For Instance:

```
private void foo() {
    System.out.println(Math.round(0.499999999999999999994));
}
```

The above code behaves differently for different Java versions.

It would be great if someone could shed some light on this issue.

Comment: post your java 6 and java 8 code

Comment: @Aaron I have included the basic code. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you stumbled on a known bug in `Java 6` which was later fixed in Java 7. This explains the weird code behaviour in `Java 6` and `Java 8`.

**Bug Info:**

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6430675

More information and beautiful explanation by @OliverCharlesworth can be found in this post:

[Why does Math.round(0.49999999999999994) return 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902968/why-does-math-round0-49999999999999994-return-1)

Excerpt from his post:

> In Java 6 (and presumably earlier), round(x) is implemented as
>   floor(x+0.5). This is a specification bug, for precisely this one
>   pathological case. Java 7 no longer mandates this broken
>   implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Closing as duplicate question maybe more suitable then

Comment: What do you mean fix @ShivamNegi? It is now fixed, so do you mean break it again in java 8, or apply the fix backwards to java 6?

Comment: The fix is to fix your code and use Java 8.  Period.  Your old Java 6 compatible code is relying on a bug, and producing incorrect results.  (If you have published results that are materially affected by this bug, then you should consider publishing a correction.)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the output of your example is `0` is a different one. `0.999999999999999999994` is a `double`. Casting an double to an it drops the decimal places of the double value.

```java
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d1 = 0.9;
        Double D1 = Double.valueOf(d1);
        int d1AsInt = (int)d1;
        System.out.println("d1 as int:\t" + d1AsInt);
        System.out.println("d1 as int:\t" + D1.intValue());
    }
}
```

If you rely on precise values you should use `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger`.

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing code. I'm seeing this behavior with `Math.round()`