# how do i avoid integer division in c++?

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_LITERS_OF_MILK_PER_CARTON = 3.78;

const double COST_PER_LITER = 0.38;

const double PROFIT_PER_CARTON = 0.27;

int main(void)
 {
    // Write your main here
    int litersOfMilk;
    int numberOfCartonsNeeded;
    double actualNumberOfCartonsNeeded;
    double totalCostOfMilk;
    double totalProfit;

// Get the liters of mild from the user
    cout << "Enter the amount of milk in liters: ";
    cin >> litersOfMilk;
    cout << endl;

//Calculate the decimal number of milk cartons needed
actualNumberOfCartonsNeeded = static_cast<double> (litersOfMilk) / MAX_LITERS_OF_MILK_PER_CARTON;

//Calculate the number of cartons needed
numberOfCartonsNeeded = static_cast<int> (actualNumberOfCartonsNeeded + 0.5);

//Calculate the total cost of producing the milk today
totalCostOfMilk = litersOfMilk * COST_PER_LITER;

//Calculate the profit of the milk for today
totalProfit = litersOfMilk * (PROFIT_PER_CARTON/MAX_LITERS_OF_MILK_PER_CARTON);

//Output the number of cartons needed, the total cost of the milk & the profit to the screen
cout << "Number of Cartons Needed: " << numberOfCartonsNeeded << endl;
cout << "Total Cost to produce " << litersOfMilk << " liters: " << totalCostOfMilk << endl;
cout << "Total Profit to produce " << litersOfMilk << " liters: " << totalProfit << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

When the program runs, every time there is division, it is doing integer division.

For example, the constant MAX_LITERS_OF_MILK_PER_CARTON is defined as 3.78, but when I divide by this constant, it is dividing by 3 instead of dividing by 3.78

How do I fix this?

Comment: `MAX_LITERS_OF_MILK_PER_CARTON` is the integer `3`.  Did you mean to define this as a double?

Comment: Just use doubles or floats instead of integers.Why are you trying to use an integer to represent a non-integer value, while use doubles in other places?

Comment: @NathanWride Or even better, don't use `double`s (or any real numbers) for money. Instead, represent them as the amount of cents, as integers. OP's risking selling their milk for $3.799999993 per gallon due to floating-point inaccuracies.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat haha that's true, I guess another option is to decide on a quanta, like cents, so you can use integers for everything which would make `MAX_LITERS_OF_MILK_PER_CARTON = 378`, `COST_PER_LITER = 38` and `PROFIT_PER_CARTON = 27`.

Comment: @NathanWride: Although you need to be careful with such a scheme: some commodities are quoted in subdivided monetary units with appropriate roundup following the multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

Your first job is to replace

```
const int MAX_LITERS_OF_MILK_PER_CARTON = 3.78;
```

with

```
const double MAX_LITERS_OF_MILK_PER_CARTON = 3.78;
```

(Didn't your compiler warn you of this?)

Then you can write

```
totalProfit = litersOfMilk * PROFIT_PER_CARTON / MAX_LITERS_OF_MILK_PER_CARTON;
```

Finally, use

```
std::round(actualNumberOfCartonsNeeded)
```

rather than

```
static_cast<int>(actualNumberOfCartonsNeeded + 0.5);
```

This adding `0.5` to effect normal rounding has pitfalls which fooled the Java bods right up to version seven!

Comment: did you miss the `int` in `const int MAX_LITERS_OF_MILK_PER_CARTON = 3.78;` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818: Yes I did rather.

Comment: You do not need to force the coercion to double.  The compiler does this automatically.  `double foo = 5 * 1.25;` is 6.25

Comment: in anycase you get +1 for something I dont dare to admit

Comment: @GrendleM: Yes this is a poor effort of mine. Blame the Barolo. Probably should hang my tools up for the day.

Comment: @Bathsheba Don't you ever blame Barolo.

Comment: It's a bit early for Barolo here... But agreed @Rotem, never blame the Barolo!

Comment: I'm not familiar with what "bods" are......? Java bods? It might also be nice if you linked to something that describes the bug you indicate that was fixed in "version 5".

Comment: @GrendleM: Of course, champagne can be consumed at any time of the day. I'd say a Beaujolais is appropriate around lunchtime, then Barolo any time after about 5pm.

Comment: @phonetagger: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902968/why-does-math-round0-49999999999999994-return-1. Silly b******. Actually looks like I'm wrong and it took them until version 7 to fix it!

Comment: OK, thanks. Still wondering what "bods" means though. Surely not "BO Data Services"? Is it just slang for "people"?

Comment: @phonetagger:It's slang for the clever guys who put Java together.