# Are there are ARM Neon instructions for round function?

Tags: c, arm, rounding, intrinsics, neon

I am trying to implement round function using ARM Neon intrinsics.

This function looks like this:

```
float roundf(float x) {
    return signbit(x) ? ceil(x - 0.5) : floor(x + 0.5);
}
```

Is there a way to do this using Neon intrinsics? If not, how to use Neon intrinsics to implement this function?

edited

After calculating the multiplication of two floats, call roundf(on armv7 and armv8).

My compiler is clang.

this can be done with `vrndaq_f32`: [https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#f:@navigationhierarchiessimdisa=[Neon]&q=vrndaq_f32](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#f:@navigationhierarchiessimdisa=%5BNeon%5D&q=vrndaq_f32) for armv8.

How to do this on **armv7**?

edited

My implementation

```
// input: float32x4_t arg
float32x4_t vector_zero = vdupq_n_f32(0.f);
float32x4_t neg_half = vdupq_n_f32(-0.5f);
float32x4_t pos_half = vdupq_n_f32(0.5f);

uint32x4_t mask = vcgeq_f32(arg, vector_zero);
uint32x4_t mask_neg = vandq_u32(mask, neg_half);
uint32x4_t mask_pos = vandq_u32(mask, pos_half);
arg = vaddq_f32(arg, (float32x4_t)mask_pos);
arg = vaddq_f32(arg, (float32x4_t)mask_neg);
int32x4_t arg_int32 = vcvtq_s32_f32(arg);
arg = vcvtq_f32_s32(arg_int32);
```

Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: Many neon instructions have optional rounding baked in. Depending on where you want to use this, it might be better to combine the rounding with whatever operation precedes it.

Comment: Are you working on the compiler?

Comment: there are no direct rounding instructions for `float` data on neon. However, you can convert to `int` with one fraction bit, then use it for rounding.

Comment: Is this for 32 or 64 bit?  AArch64 has the `FRINTZ` instruction which I think is what you want.

Comment: This is what, round to nearest with ties toward 0.0?  So it's the C `roundf()` function?  As Nate says, this can be done with `frint` for AArch64.  Clang really does inline `round()` as `frinta`: https://godbolt.org/z/o8arE1795.  But not for ARM32.

Comment: this can be done with vrndaq_f32: https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#f:@navigationhierarchiessimdisa=[Neon]&q=vrndaq_f32 for armv8.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's rounding ties away from zero, I forgot which way `signbit` goes.

Comment: You should be aware that `floor(x + 0.5)` has some corner cases where it does the wrong thing. E.g., assuming IEEE 754 binary32 format for `float` and round-ties-to-even for arithmetic operations, if `x = 0x1.fffffep-2` (around 0.49999997) then it should round to `0`, but `round(x + 0.5)` will round it to `1.0`. Similarly, if `x = 10000001` (which is exactly representable in binary32 format) then under normal rounding rules `x + 0.5` will round `x` to `10000002` instead of `10000001`

Comment: Sorry, that `round(x + 0.5)` should say `floor(x + 0.5)` in the previous comment. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9902968/270986

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is VERY expensive, both in cycle counts and register utilization.

Provided `-(2^30) <= arg < (2^30)`, you can do following:

```
int32x4_t argi = vcvtq_n_s32_f32(arg, 1);
argi = vsraq_n_s32(argi, argi, 31);
argi = vrshrq_n_s32(argi, 1);
arg = vcvtq_f32_s32(argi);
```

It doesn't require any other register than `arg` itself, and it will be done with 4 inexpensive instructions. And it works both for `aarch32` and `aarch64`

[godblot link](https://godbolt.org/z/zMh6h58hY)

Answer (score 2):

It's important that you define *which* form of rounding you really want. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) for a sense of how many rounding choices there are.

From your code-snippet, you are asking for *commercial* or *symmetric* rounding which is round-away from zero for ties. For ARMv8 / ARM64, `vrndaq_f32` should do that.

> The SSE4 `_mm_round_ps` and ARMv8 ARM-NEON `vrndnq_f32` do *bankers rounding* i.e. round-to-nearest (even).

Comment: Are you sure about `vrndaq_f32`?  The manual link in the question says it rounds "to nearest with ties **Away**", i.e. `round()` not `nearbyint()` like `_mm_round_ps`.  Also, if ARM blends work like x86 `vblendps`, you don't need to *compute* a select mask, you can literally use the FP bit patterns as selectors.  -0.0 and +0.0 will still round to some kind of zero, I think actually preserving the input sign.  (Which wouldn't happen if you compared for equality against +0.0)

Comment: Let me double-checking my test coverage on ARM64 then. If ``vrndaq_f32`` is supposed to be like C99 ``roundf`` then something's amiss.

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually using ``vrndnq_f32`` which is ``FRINTN`` which is bankers.   ``vrndaq_f32`` is ``FRINTA`` which is nearest, ties away from zero.