# How do I round off a Float value in C

Tags: c

I'm looking for function which can Round off a float value in C ,Suppose have number 0.1153846 should be rounded off till 6 decimal producing output as 0.115385

Though there is function in objective c like lroundf() but not sure how can use it in my context.

I'm on gcc compiler and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [round() for float in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c)

Comment: Not a good duplicate:   This post is interested in rounding to a number of decimal places (6).  Suggested [dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c) is for rounding to a whole number.  There are subtle and important different issues involved.

Answer (score 1):

```
float f = 0.1153846;
f = floor(f * 1000000) / 1000000;
```

This should work.

Comment: This is something I also come up with. let me check how its working

Comment: It alone won't work guess something like f+0.5 needs to be done!!

Comment: @KerrekSB +5 should be added as you mentioned to round up to the next digit. thanks.

Comment: f = floor((f * 1000000)+0.5) / 1000000; would be ok

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: Yeah, that's the one :-)

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar `floor((f * 1000000)+0.5) / 1000000;` has a number of problems 1) Negative numbers, 2) values when `f * 1000000` ULP is 0.5 or 1.0, 3) value when `f * 1000000` is just under 0.5.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do

```
  double x = 0.1153846;
  double rx = round (x * 1e6) * 1.e-6;
```

However, remember that IEEE 754 floating points are binary, with base 2 mantissa.

Comment: but output comes to be 0.115380 which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Try with `1e6` and `1.e-6` instead

Comment: A slightly more pedantic answer would use `/` as in `double rx = round (x * 1e6) /1.e6;`

Answer (score 1):

It's quite unusual for float to be a decimal type, that means that whatever you do, the result of the rounding will most often than not not be representable in a float and will be adjusted again to match a representable number.

If such a rounding is really needed for computational purpose, a floating point type is probably not the correct type to use.

If it is just for display purpose, use the control the `printf` family give you.

Answer (score 1):

```
int precision = 3;
float num = 1.63322;
printf("%.*f",precision,num);
```

Comment: This does not round `num`.  It does print a rounded version, but `num` is not affected.